# How to pass url parameters to JSF?

Tags: jsf

I haven't managed to find a way to pass parameters to JSF pages through URL parameters.

```
http://www.example.com/jsfApp.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Could someone point me at the right direction with this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you're using JSPs, I'll assume that you're using JSF 1.x.

To create a link with query parameters, use `h:outputLink` with `f:param`:

```
<h:outputLink value="page.jsf">
    <f:param name="param1" value="value1" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</h:outputLink>
```

The `value` can be set dynamically with help of EL.

To set them in the managed bean automagically, you need to define each as `managed-property` in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.Bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>param1</property-name>
        <value>#{param.param1}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>param2</property-name>
        <value>#{param.param2}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

The imlicit EL variable `#{param}` refers to the request parameter map as you know it from the Servlet API. The bean should of course already have both the `param1` and `param2` properties with the appropriate getters/setters definied.

If you'd like to execute some logic directly after they are been set, make use of the `@PostConstruct` annotation:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    doSomethingWith(param1, param2);
}
```

For more hints about passing parameters and that kind of stuff around in JSF, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) useful.

The JSF 2.x approach would be using either `@ManagedProperty` in the backing bean class, or `<f:viewParam>` in the target view. See also this question: [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)