# ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, viewparams, managed-property

What is the difference between defining View Params like this:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{someBean.id}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

And defining the property in the ManagedBean like this:

```
@Inject @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

### [`<f:viewParam>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/f/viewparam):

- Sets the value during update model values phase only (since it extends [`UIInput`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiinput)).
- The set value is not available during [`@PostConstruct`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html), so you need an additional [`<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/f/event) inside the [`<f:metadata>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/f/metadata) to do initialization/preloading based on the set values. Since JSF 2.2 you could use `<f:viewAction>` for that instead.
- Allows for nested [`<f:converter>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/f/converter) and [`<f:validator>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/f/validator) for more fine-grained conversion/validation. Even a [`<h:message>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/html_basic/message) can be attached.
- Can be automatically included as GET query string in outcome target URLs using `includeViewParams` attribute of [`<h:link>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/html_basic/link) or `includeViewParams=true` request parameter in any URL.
- Can be used on a [`@RequestScoped`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/enterprise/context/requestscoped) bean, but it requires the bean to be [`@ViewScoped`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/bean/viewscoped) if you want the view parameters to survive any validation failures caused by forms enclosed in the view, otherwise you need to manually retain all request parameters for the subsequent requests by [`<f:param>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/vdldoc/f/param) in the `UICommand` components, because the `<f:viewParam>` will be set on every request.

**Example**:

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="user_id" name="id" value="#{bean.user}"
        required="true" requiredMessage="Invalid page access. Please use a link from within the system."
        converter="userConverter" converterMessage="Unknown user ID."
    />
</f:metadata>
<h:message for="user_id" />
```

with

```java
private User user;
```

and an [`@FacesConverter("userConverter")`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/convert/facesconverter). Invoking page by http://example.com/context/user.xhtml?id=123 will pass the `id` parameter through the converter and set the `User` object as a bean property.

---

### [`@ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/annotation/managedproperty):

- Sets the value immediately after bean's construction.
- Set value is available during [`@PostConstruct`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/annotation/postconstruct) which allows easy initialization/preloading of other properties based on the set value.
- Does **not** allow for declarative conversion/validation in view.
- Does **not** support being automatically included in outcome target URLs.
- Can be used on a bean of any scope, but it will be set only during bean's construction instead of on every request.

**Example**:

```java
@Inject @ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")
private Long id;

private User user;

@EJB
private UserService userService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    user = userService.find(id);
}
```

Do note that you have to manage conversion and validation yourself whenever `user` is `null` by fiddling with [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/context/facescontext#addMessage-java.lang.String-jakarta.faces.application.FacesMessage-) inside the `@PostConstruct` method. Also note that when `#{param.id}` is not a valid number, then an exception will be thrown before `@PostConstruct` is hit. If you want to deal with it, then you'd probably better make it a `private String id`. But much better is to use `<f:viewParam>`.

---

You *can* use them both when both [`@PostConstruct`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/annotation/postconstruct) and `includeViewParams` are mandatory. You only won't be able to apply fine-grained conversion/validation anymore.

---

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: There are other alternative to retrieve request parameters in exceptional cases: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("parametername");

Comment: @angel: Only when the bean has a broader scope than request scope which makes `@ManagedProperty` on a request parameter impossible.

Comment: hi @BalusC I do rely on the value of id retrieved from param.id using managedproperty on a second post. How can I include it using f:param? thanks a lot

Comment: what do you mean that the set value is not available during @PostConstruct.  If not then, when?  How do you use <f:viewAction> in this scenario?

Comment: @thufir: It's set during update model values phase. The postconstruct runs far before that, directly after bean's construction and dependency injection. It is available in the listener method which is invoked by `<f:event type="preRenderView">` or the upcoming JSF 2.2 `<f:viewAction>`.

Comment: Can you use f:viewParam for multiple GET parameters?

Comment: @feder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794149/jsf-2-viewparam-with-multiple-values

Answer (score 6):

2 other differences:

- `@ManagedProperty` is usable only with beans managed by JSF, not with beans managed by CDI (`@Named`);

  - <strike>`<f:viewParam>` works only with parameters of GET requests.</strike>

Comment: Therefore you could use the annotation: org.omnifaces.cdi.Param