# ViewScoped bean getting constructed on every request... part 99

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, lifecycle, view-scope, postconstruct

ARGH...  This seems to have a hundred answers and I haven't found one that works for me, so I guess I will actually ask it again.  Here is my scenario:

My site technically has a single page whose contents get swapped out rather than having multiple pages that you navigate to.  The starting point is this chunk:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head />
  <h:body>
    <ui:include src="resourceInclude.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="main.xhtml" />
  </h:body>
</f:view>
```

The resourceInclude.xhtml includes my css file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="test.css" target="head" />
</ui:composition>
```

And main.xhtml is the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:panelGroup styleClass="test-container" layout="block">
    <h:form id="main-form">
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="test-header" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="navigation" layout="block">
          <ul>
            <li><h:commandLink action="#{viewSelector.setModeHome}">
                <h:outputText value="Home" />
              </h:commandLink></li>
            <li><h:commandLink action="#{viewSelector.setModeReports}">
                <h:outputText value="ASAP Reports" />
              </h:commandLink></li>
            <li><h:commandLink action="#{viewSelector.setModeSupport}">
                <h:outputText value="Technical Support" />
              </h:commandLink></li>
            <li><h:commandLink action="#{viewSelector.setModeHelp}">
                <h:outputText value="Help" />
              </h:commandLink></li>
          </ul>
        </h:panelGroup>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="test-content" layout="block">
        <ui:include src="#{viewSelector.modeName}-view.xhtml" />
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="test-footer" layout="block">
        <h:messages />
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
  </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

It consists of three `h:panelGroup`s.  The first is a set of four general navigation links, each link changes the `viewSelector.modeName` value which is used to include the contents in the second `h:panelGroup` thusly `<ui:include src="#{viewSelector.modeName}-view.xhtml" />`.  I have stripped this down for this example so each view is basically this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:panelGroup styleClass="test-home-view">
    <p>home</p>
  </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

The third `h:panelGroup` is a footer for all the messages to debug what is going wrong.

Anyway, every time I click one of the navigation links, the constructor of the viewSelector bean gets called.  This is what my viewSelector bean looks like:

```
package org.mitre.asias.aires.controller;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


@ManagedBean( name="viewSelector" )
@ViewScoped
public class ViewSelector {
    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( ViewSelector.class );
    private Mode mode = Mode.HOME;
    public static final String PORTLET_NAME = "Test";

    public static enum Mode {
        HOME(1, "home"),
        REPORTS(2, "reports"),
        SUPPORT(3, "support"),
        HELP(4, "help");

        private int value;
        private String name;

        private Mode( int value, String name ) {
            this.value = value;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public ViewSelector() {
        log.trace( "constructing new ViewSelector" );
    }

    public Mode getMode() {
        log.trace( "getting mode" );

        return mode;
    }

    public String getModeName() {
        log.debug( "in getmodename" );
        return getMode().getName();
    }

    public String getPortletName() {
        return PORTLET_NAME;
    }

    public boolean isModeReports() {
        return getMode() == Mode.REPORTS;
    }

    public void setMode( Mode mode ) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public void setModeHelp() {
        setMode( Mode.HELP );
    }

    public void setModeHome() {
        setMode( mode = Mode.HOME );
    }

    public void setModeReports() {
        setMode( mode = Mode.REPORTS );
    }

    public void setModeSupport() {
        setMode( mode = Mode.SUPPORT );
    }
}
```

I know I must be doing something the wrong way, or else I missing something central as to how JSF works.  Any Input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EL in `<ui:include src>` is causing that.

If disabling the partial state saving in `web.xml` as per [issue 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492) is not an option,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then you need to replace

```
<ui:include src="#{viewSelector.modeName}-view.xhtml" />
```

by something like

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{viewSelector.mode == 'HOME'}">
    <ui:include src="home-view.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{viewSelector.mode == 'REPORTS'}">
    <ui:include src="reports-view.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{viewSelector.mode == 'SUPPORT'}">
    <ui:include src="support-view.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{viewSelector.mode == 'HELP'}">
    <ui:include src="help-view.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

A similar question has at least been asked once before :)

- [How to ajax-refresh dynamic include content by navigation menu? (JSF SPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-the-main-content-part-by-navigation-menu)

Comment: Once again, thanks.  You've gotta get tired of hearing that :).  Does EL in any `ui` element cause this, or just the `ui:include`?  in other words if i switched to templating instead, would i still run into this issue? Oh, and I promise to do more searching next time...

Comment: It was hard to find though, also for me :) Luckily I recalled the subject so that I could just find it more easily. As to the problem, this will only occur when you bind an attribute of any **tag handler** by EL to a view scoped bean. Tag handlers runs during view build time instead of view render time. Tag handlers are all JSTL `<c:xxx>` tags, some JSF `<f:xxx>` tags and a few Facelets `<ui:xxx>` tags. In this (related) blog you can find them all in a nice table: http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/blog/c:foreach-vs-ui:repeat-in-facelets

Comment: By coincidence, I was last weeks busy writing a "Communication in JSF 2.0" blog article which I've posted just a hour ago. There's a chapter which handles this particular problem in a bit more detail: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers

Comment: I switched to your suggestion with the `h:panelGroup rendered="#{el}"`, but have a problem.  I have a second section that also has 4 modes, one of which is the active mode.  In that, the 4th mode relies on a variable set in the third mode and can only be navigated to from that third mode.  However, the `rendered` does not seem to prevent the `ui:include` from including the page.  This makes sense as `ui:include` gets processed to build the page and `rendered` would only get checked during render.  Is there a way to prevent `ui:include`?

Comment: This is indeed an awkward side effect of this chicken-egg issue :/ Is disabling the partial state saving not an option? In theory, this could be solved by `@CustomScoped` which holds the view scoped beans straight in the session scope instead of the view state. If I have time left later the day I will experiment with it.

Comment: Breaking this case out into a minimal project shows that I cannot reproduce.  This must mean my assumption is wrong.  The `ui:include` inside of the `h:panelGroup rendered="false"` does not appear to get called in my test case.  I am not sure how my actual project differs so I will post an edit in my comment with more details.

Comment: I have created a minimal test case that demonstrates this issue.  I have posted it as a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7534107/516433).  I have the example as a maven project if you want to take a look (though all the code is also posted in the linked to question)