# ViewScoped call PostConstruct on each RestoreView JSF LifeCycle

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Well, I have a selectOneMenu Component (primefaces) that loads another selectOneMenu, see bellow:

```xhtml
<h:outputLabel value="Tabela: *" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuTabela"
    converter="entityConverter"
    value="#{orcamentoMB.tabelaSelecionada}" effect="fade"
    required="true" requiredMessage="A Tabela é obrigatória">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma Tabela" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{orcamentoMB.tabelas}" var="tabela"
        itemLabel="#{tabela.nome}" itemValue="#{tabela}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="selectOneMenuProcedimento" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputText value="Procedimento: *" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuProcedimento"
    converter="entityConverter" filter="true"
    filterMatchMode="contains"
    value="#{orcamentoMB.itemTabelaProcedimentoSelecionado}"
    effect="fade" required="true"
    requiredMessage="O procedimento é obrigatório">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um Procedimento" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{orcamentoMB.tabelaSelecionada.itens}"
        var="item" itemLabel="#{item.procedimento.nome}"
        itemValue="#{item}" />
    <p:ajax event="change"
        update="localAplicacao, selectOneMenuDente, selectOneMenuFace" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So, when the first SelectOneMenu change the second is loaded, but when this occurrs the method PostConstruct is called again, i don't know why. I'm using a Abstract class with @PostConstruct anotation, seE:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
    logger.info("Iniciando PostConstruct...");

    init();
//  CampoPesquisa.clear();

    String action = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
            .get("action");
    if (action != null) {
        if (action.equals("alterar")) {
        String id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
                .get("id");     
        buscarBean(Integer.valueOf(id));
        alterar();
        } else if (action.equals("novo")) {
        novo();
        }
    } else {
        buscarBeans();
    }

    }
```

And in my concret class, i do it:

```
@Override
    public void init() {
    dentistas = (List<Dentista>) boPadrao
            .findByNamedQuery(Dentista.FIND_ALL_COMPLETO);
    pacientes = (List<Paciente>) boPadrao
            .findByNamedQuery(Paciente.FIND_ALL_COMPLETO);
    situacoes = (List<SituacaoOrcamento>) boPadrao
            .findByNamedQuery(SituacaoOrcamento.FIND_ALL);
    tabelas = (List<TabelaProcedimento>) boPadrao
            .findByNamedQuery(TabelaProcedimento.FIND_ALL_SIMPLES);
    cartoesCredito = (List<CartaoCredito>) boPadrao
            .findByNamedQuery(CartaoCredito.FIND_ALL);
    formasPagamento = (List<FormaPagamento>) boPadrao
            .findByNamedQuery(FormaPagamento.FIND_ALL);
    tabelasProtese = (List<TabelaProtese>) boPadrao
            .findByNamedQuery(TabelaProtese.FIND_ALL_SIMPLES);

    ParametroSistema param = (ParametroSistema) parametroSistemaHelper
            .getParametroByCodigo("MAXIMO_DESCONTO").get(0);
    maxDesconto = Double.valueOf(param.getValor_campo1().toString())
            .doubleValue();

    // Checa se foi passada a ação de "pagar"
    String action = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
            .get("action");
    if (action != null && action.equals("pagar")) {
        Integer id = Integer.valueOf(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));
        iniciarPagamento(id);
    }
    }
```

I debuged the LifeCycle of JSF, and i've noted that @PostConstruct is called on "RestoView" phase after change the First SelectOneMenu.

See that:

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.mb.BasicCrudMBNewImpl:257] - Iniciando PostConstruct...
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery Dentista.findAllCompleto sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select dentista0_.id as id36_0_, pessoafisi1_.id as id2_1_, estadocivi2_.id as id0_2_, sexo3_.id as id0_3_, uf4_.id as id0_4_, dentista0_.caixa_saldo_atual as caixa2_36_0_, dentista0_.cro as cro36_0_, dentista0_.id_pessoa_fisica as id4_36_0_, pessoafisi1_1_.bairro as bairro2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.cep as cep2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.cidade as cidade2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.complemento as compleme5_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.data_cadastro as data6_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.email as email2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.endereco as endereco2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.foto as foto2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.nome as nome2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.observacao as observacao2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.operadora_telefone_1 as operadora12_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.operadora_telefone_2 as operadora13_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.operadora_telefone_3 as operadora14_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.id_situacao as id18_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.telefone1 as telefone15_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.telefone2 as telefone16_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.telefone3 as telefone17_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.id_uf as id19_2_1_, pessoafisi1_.cpf as cpf28_1_, pessoafisi1_.data_nascimento as data2_28_1_, pessoafisi1_.id_estado_civil as id5_28_1_, pessoafisi1_.rg as rg28_1_, pessoafisi1_.id_sexo as id6_28_1_, estadocivi2_.codigo as codigo0_2_, estadocivi2_.descricao as descricao0_2_, estadocivi2_.tipo as tipo0_2_, sexo3_.codigo as codigo0_3_, sexo3_.descricao as descricao0_3_, sexo3_.tipo as tipo0_3_, uf4_.codigo as codigo0_4_, uf4_.descricao as descricao0_4_, uf4_.tipo as tipo0_4_ from dentista dentista0_ inner join pessoa_fisica pessoafisi1_ on dentista0_.id_pessoa_fisica=pessoafisi1_.id inner join pessoa pessoafisi1_1_ on pessoafisi1_.id=pessoafisi1_1_.id inner join lov estadocivi2_ on pessoafisi1_.id_estado_civil=estadocivi2_.id inner join lov sexo3_ on pessoafisi1_.id_sexo=sexo3_.id inner join lov uf4_ on pessoafisi1_1_.id_uf=uf4_.id order by pessoafisi1_1_.nome
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 5
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery Paciente.findAllCompleto sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select paciente0_.id as id7_0_, pessoafisi1_.id as id2_1_, paciente0_.alergias as alergias7_0_, paciente0_.anestesia as anestesia7_0_, paciente0_.caixa_saldo_atual as caixa4_7_0_, paciente0_.id_dentista as id13_7_0_, paciente0_.diabetico as diabetico7_0_, paciente0_.doenca_coracao as doenca6_7_0_, paciente0_.gravida as gravida7_0_, paciente0_.hemorragia as hemorragia7_0_, paciente0_.hipertenso as hipertenso7_0_, paciente0_.id_indicado_por as id14_7_0_, paciente0_.medicamentos as medicam10_7_0_, paciente0_.outros_anamnese as outros11_7_0_, paciente0_.id_pessoa_fisica as id15_7_0_, paciente0_.id_tipo_indicacao as id16_7_0_, paciente0_.tratamento_medico as tratamento12_7_0_, pessoafisi1_1_.bairro as bairro2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.cep as cep2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.cidade as cidade2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.complemento as compleme5_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.data_cadastro as data6_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.email as email2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.endereco as endereco2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.foto as foto2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.nome as nome2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.observacao as observacao2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.operadora_telefone_1 as operadora12_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.operadora_telefone_2 as operadora13_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.operadora_telefone_3 as operadora14_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.id_situacao as id18_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.telefone1 as telefone15_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.telefone2 as telefone16_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.telefone3 as telefone17_2_1_, pessoafisi1_1_.id_uf as id19_2_1_, pessoafisi1_.cpf as cpf28_1_, pessoafisi1_.data_nascimento as data2_28_1_, pessoafisi1_.id_estado_civil as id5_28_1_, pessoafisi1_.rg as rg28_1_, pessoafisi1_.id_sexo as id6_28_1_ from paciente paciente0_ inner join pessoa_fisica pessoafisi1_ on paciente0_.id_pessoa_fisica=pessoafisi1_.id inner join pessoa pessoafisi1_1_ on pessoafisi1_.id=pessoafisi1_1_.id order by pessoafisi1_1_.nome
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 5
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery SituacaoOrcamento.findAll sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select situacaoor0_.id as id0_, situacaoor0_.codigo as codigo0_, situacaoor0_.descricao as descricao0_, situacaoor0_.tipo as tipo0_ from lov situacaoor0_ where situacaoor0_.tipo=10 order by situacaoor0_.descricao
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 5
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery TabelaProcedimento.findAllSimples sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select tabelaproc0_.id as id9_, tabelaproc0_.nome as nome9_, tabelaproc0_.observacao as observacao9_ from tabela_procedimento tabelaproc0_ order by tabelaproc0_.nome
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 2
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery CartaoCredito.findAll sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select cartaocred0_.id as id31_, cartaocred0_.bandeira as bandeira31_, cartaocred0_.numero_maximo_parcelas as numero3_31_, cartaocred0_.taxa_maxima_desconto as taxa4_31_, cartaocred0_.valor_minimo_parcela as valor5_31_ from cartao_credito cartaocred0_ order by cartaocred0_.bandeira
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 3
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery FormaPagamento.findAll sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select formapagam0_.id as id0_, formapagam0_.codigo as codigo0_, formapagam0_.descricao as descricao0_, formapagam0_.tipo as tipo0_ from lov formapagam0_ where formapagam0_.tipo=12 order by formapagam0_.descricao
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 4
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery TabelaProtese.findAllSimples sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select tabelaprot0_.id as id6_, tabelaprot0_.nome as nome6_, tabelaprot0_.observacao as observacao6_, tabelaprot0_.id_protetico as id4_6_ from tabela_protese tabelaprot0_ order by tabelaprot0_.nome
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 1
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:114] - Procurando pela query: SELECT c FROM ParametroSistema c WHERE c.codigo = :codigo
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:123] - Param: codigo, Value: MAXIMO_DESCONTO
Hibernate: select parametros0_.id as id15_, parametros0_.codigo as codigo15_, parametros0_.descricao as descricao15_, parametros0_.descricao_campo1 as descricao4_15_, parametros0_.descricao_campo2 as descricao5_15_, parametros0_.descricao_campo3 as descricao6_15_, parametros0_.valor_campo1 as valor7_15_, parametros0_.valor_campo2 as valor8_15_, parametros0_.valor_campo3 as valor9_15_ from parametro_sistema parametros0_ where parametros0_.codigo=?
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:131] - Objetos Encontrados: 1
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.mb.BasicCrudMBNewImpl:212] - Buscando beans sem filtro
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:71] - Procurando pela namedQuery Orcamento.findAllCompleto sem nenhum parametro
Hibernate: select orcamento0_.id as id14_0_, dentista1_.id as id36_1_, paciente2_.id as id7_2_, usuario3_.id as id12_3_, situacaoor4_.id as id0_4_, orcamento0_.data_emissao as data2_14_0_, orcamento0_.data_validade as data3_14_0_, orcamento0_.id_dentista_orcou as id8_14_0_, orcamento0_.desconto as desconto14_0_, orcamento0_.observacoes as observac5_14_0_, orcamento0_.id_paciente as id9_14_0_, orcamento0_.id_situacao as id10_14_0_, orcamento0_.total_geral as total6_14_0_, orcamento0_.total_pago as total7_14_0_, orcamento0_.id_usuario as id11_14_0_, dentista1_.caixa_saldo_atual as caixa2_36_1_, dentista1_.cro as cro36_1_, dentista1_.id_pessoa_fisica as id4_36_1_, paciente2_.alergias as alergias7_2_, paciente2_.anestesia as anestesia7_2_, paciente2_.caixa_saldo_atual as caixa4_7_2_, paciente2_.id_dentista as id13_7_2_, paciente2_.diabetico as diabetico7_2_, paciente2_.doenca_coracao as doenca6_7_2_, paciente2_.gravida as gravida7_2_, paciente2_.hemorragia as hemorragia7_2_, paciente2_.hipertenso as hipertenso7_2_, paciente2_.id_indicado_por as id14_7_2_, paciente2_.medicamentos as medicam10_7_2_, paciente2_.outros_anamnese as outros11_7_2_, paciente2_.id_pessoa_fisica as id15_7_2_, paciente2_.id_tipo_indicacao as id16_7_2_, paciente2_.tratamento_medico as tratamento12_7_2_, usuario3_.login as login12_3_, usuario3_.id_pessoa_fisica as id4_12_3_, usuario3_.senha as senha12_3_, situacaoor4_.codigo as codigo0_4_, situacaoor4_.descricao as descricao0_4_, situacaoor4_.tipo as tipo0_4_ from orcamento orcamento0_ inner join dentista dentista1_ on orcamento0_.id_dentista_orcou=dentista1_.id inner join paciente paciente2_ on orcamento0_.id_paciente=paciente2_.id left outer join usuario usuario3_ on orcamento0_.id_usuario=usuario3_.id inner join lov situacaoor4_ on orcamento0_.id_situacao=situacaoor4_.id order by orcamento0_.data_emissao desc
INFO  06/03/2014 23:23:26 [br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAOImpl:78] - Objetos Encontrados: 11
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
Hibernate: select itens0_.id_tabela_procedimento as id4_1_, itens0_.id as id1_, itens0_.id as id19_0_, itens0_.id_procedimento as id3_19_0_, itens0_.id_tabela_procedimento as id4_19_0_, itens0_.valor as valor19_0_ from item_tabela_procedimento itens0_ where itens0_.id_tabela_procedimento=?
Hibernate: select procedimen0_.id as id26_0_, procedimen0_.cor_hexa as cor2_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_especialidade as id5_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_local_aplicacao as id6_26_0_, procedimen0_.nome as nome26_0_, procedimen0_.sobre_procedimento as sobre4_26_0_ from procedimento procedimen0_ where procedimen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select procedimen0_.id as id26_0_, procedimen0_.cor_hexa as cor2_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_especialidade as id5_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_local_aplicacao as id6_26_0_, procedimen0_.nome as nome26_0_, procedimen0_.sobre_procedimento as sobre4_26_0_ from procedimento procedimen0_ where procedimen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select procedimen0_.id as id26_0_, procedimen0_.cor_hexa as cor2_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_especialidade as id5_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_local_aplicacao as id6_26_0_, procedimen0_.nome as nome26_0_, procedimen0_.sobre_procedimento as sobre4_26_0_ from procedimento procedimen0_ where procedimen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select procedimen0_.id as id26_0_, procedimen0_.cor_hexa as cor2_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_especialidade as id5_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_local_aplicacao as id6_26_0_, procedimen0_.nome as nome26_0_, procedimen0_.sobre_procedimento as sobre4_26_0_ from procedimento procedimen0_ where procedimen0_.id=?
Hibernate: select procedimen0_.id as id26_0_, procedimen0_.cor_hexa as cor2_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_especialidade as id5_26_0_, procedimen0_.id_local_aplicacao as id6_26_0_, procedimen0_.nome as nome26_0_, procedimen0_.sobre_procedimento as sobre4_26_0_ from procedimento procedimen0_ where procedimen0_.id=?
END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

My ManagedBean is "@ViewScoped" and i tried almost everything but i don't know what is the problem.

**SOLUTION:**

I just updated my JSF version from 2.0 to 2.2.4 and everything works fine.

Comment: Problem could be just a bug in your JSF implementation version. Check which version it is. There are several related issues in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449873/viewscoped-bean-getting-constructed-on-every-request-part-99

Comment: what is the last version of JSF ? This last version fix this bug ?

Comment: From Mojarra implementation you've got 2.2.5 and 2.1.27 versions. New ones are going to be released soon.