# How to fetch multiple parameters with the same key into a JSF managed bean

Tags: parameters, jsf-2, request

Let's say I have this request:

```
myview.xhtml?a=1&b=par1&b=par2
```

In `myview.xhtml`

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="a" value="#{myBean.a}"/>
  <f:viewParam name="b" value="#{myBean.b}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

In `MyBean`

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.a}")
String a;

@ManagedProperty("#{param.b}")
String b;
```

I thought that `setB(String b)` would be invoked twice, so I can add the items to a `List`, but it was invoked just once, with the first value (`par1`).

I also tried to transform b into a `List<String>` but JSF is not evaluating as a `List`.

So, my question is how to inject multiple parameter values with the same key, **using `@ManagedProperty`**. (right now I am getting the `paramterValues` manually)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. You are using both `<f:viewParam>` and `@ManagedProperty`. [Usually you use the one or the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id).

With `@ManagedProperty` this is pretty easy. You need `#{paramValues.b}` instead of `#{param.b}`. This does under the covers the same as [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) which returns a `String[]` with all parameter values on the given name.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{paramValues.b}")
private String[] b;
```

With `<f:viewParam>` I don't see any ways. I have the impression that this is simply not supported. But I have also the impression that you don't need it at all.

---

**Update**: by coincidende I encountered the following comment in the `decode()` method while crawling in the source of [`UIViewParameter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewParameter.html) (Mojarra 2.1.1, line 218 and on) and I thought back to this question:

```
// QUESTION can we move forward and support an array? no different than UISelectMany; perhaps need to know
// if the value expression is single or multi-valued
// ANSWER: I'd rather not right now.
String paramValue = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(getName());
```

So, it's "by design" simply not supported on `<f:viewParam>`.

Comment: True, I may need only `@ManagedProperty` here. `"#{paramValues}` works greatly, thanks (+1). But, what should I use when I am qualifying my beans as `@Named`, since `@ManagedProperty`'s javadoc says: _If this annotation is present on a class that does not have the ManagedBean annotation, the implementation must take no action on this annotation._ ?

Comment: No idea. I have not looked at CDI closely.

Comment: Well probably it will depend on the implementation. Since I'm using Spring to wire my `@Named` beans, then something like `@Inject @Named("#{param.a}")` will never work. Anyway, this ain't of the scope of this question...