# How to pass argument to method in ui:repeat or c:forEach

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, el

I would like to do be like this:

```
<c:forEach items="#{myService.getServiceById(${item.edit_id})}" var="item">
```

`${item.edit_id})` part of the `myService.getServiceById()` should be GET param called edit_id. I want to pass it.

It's not working for me.. I've tried in numerous ways and by adding params in other fields (like hidden inputs), no luck. I need to grab that edit_id param from url and pass it to loop. Any solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7775203/3803447

Comment: Geinmachi, thnx for link. But now, how to write c:forEach or ui:repeat with it?

Comment: You seem to have got stuck with a wrong approach. The EL syntax is also technically incorrect. EL things (`#{}` and `${}`) cannot be nested. There are several ways in which query string parameters can be passed to a managed bean such as by using `<f:viewParam>` depending upon the functional requirements.

Comment: So how to write it if they cannot be nested.. ?

Comment: Just don't nest them at all. You should see `#{...}` as one big scope where various variables can interact with each other.

Comment: Balus C, but I managed to nest them and now it works (I used @ManagedProperty("#{param.parameter}") from link). Look: 

#{myService.getServiceById(item.id)}

How would you make it any other way? Is this bad approach? It works now.