# JSF2 Managed Bean variable initialization

Tags: jsf-2, initialization

I'm having some problems with bean initialization. I have an "edit" form to update 
some user data. The user is previously created in the database and 
I retrieve successfuly the data and put it in the form.

This is the form with id parameter 1 (/cms/admin/users/edit.jsf?id=1):

```
<h:panelGrid styleClass="general-form" columns="3" id="ajaxForm">
<h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{cms['users.add.name']}" />
<p:inputText required="true" id="name"
    value="#{editUserController.user.name}"
    label="#{cms['users.add.name']}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="name" />

<h:outputLabel value="#{cms['users.add.lastname']}" />
<p:inputText id="lastname" label="#{cms['users.add.lastname']}"
    required="true" value="#{editUserController.user.lastname}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="lastname" />

<h:outputLabel value="#{cms['users.add.username']}" />
<p:inputText id="username" required="true"
    label="#{cms['users.add.username']}"
    value="#{editUserController.user.username}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
</p:inputText>

<p:message for="username" />

<h:outputLabel value="#{cms['users.add.password']}" />
<p:password id="password" required="true"
    value="#{editUserController.user.password}"
    promptLabel="#{cms['users.error.enterPassword']}"
    weakLabel="#{cms['users.error.weakPassword']}"
    goodLabel="#{cms['users.error.goodPassword']}"
    strongLabel="#{cms['users.error.strongPassword']}"
    binding="#{password}" label="#{cms['users.add.password']}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="6" />
</p:password>
<p:message for="password" />

<h:outputLabel value="#{cms['users.add.confirmPassword']}" />
<p:password id="passwordConfirm" required="true"
    value="#{editUserController.confirmPassword}"
    promptLabel="#{cms['users.error.enterPassword']}"
    weakLabel="#{cms['users.error.weakPassword']}"
    goodLabel="#{cms['users.error.goodPassword']}"
    strongLabel="#{cms['users.error.strongPassword']}"
    label="#{cms['users.add.confirmPassword']}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="6" />
    <f:validator validatorId="passwordValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="password" value="#{password.value}" />
</p:password>
<p:message for="passwordConfirm" />

<h:outputLabel value="#{cms['users.add.active']}" />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{editUserController.user.active}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Sí" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText value="" />

<h:outputLabel value="#{cms['users.add.role']}" />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{editUserController.securityRole}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{editUserController.securityRoles}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText value="" />

<h:outputText value="" />
<p:commandButton action="#{editUserController.saveUser}"
    style="margin-top:20px;" ajax="false"
    value="#{cms['general.save']}"></p:commandButton>
```

This is the Managed Bean (EditUserController.java):

```
public class EditUserController extends GeneralController implements
    Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")
private Integer id;

private UserService userService;

private SecurityRoleService securityRoleService;

private User user;

private String confirmPassword;

private Map<String, SecurityRole> securityRoles;

private String securityRole;

@PostConstruct
public String checkUser() {
    try {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        this.id = Integer.parseInt(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));

        setUser(userService.findById(id));
        Map<String, SecurityRole> secRoles = new ListUtils<String>().toMap(
                securityRoleService.findAll(0, 30, "", ""), "name");

        setSecurityRoles(secRoles);

        setSecurityRole(user.getSecurityRole().getId().toString());

        return "edit";
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        return FATAL;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return FATAL;
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        return FATAL;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return FATAL;
    }
}

public String saveUser() {
    try {   
        System.out.println("User saved!!");
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(MessageProvider.getMessageProvider()
                        .getValue("cms", "general.error")));
        return ERROR;
    }
}

//getters and setters ...
```

With the @Postconstruct method I initialize the *user* variable according to the id *param*.
Then the form is displayed correctly with all data prefilled. But when I click in the 
commandButton I get an exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'editUserController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

I understand where is the error. In the @Postconstruct method the variable *id* has not 
been "initialized" because there is not any *id* parameter in the request. I know I can solve this
scoping the bean to session or application, but it does not make any sense to have the bean there
just to perform this simple action.

How can I do this simple form? I just want to get an id parameter, show a form with prefilled data
then give the posibility to change the data an finally submit the form to save the new values
 into the DB

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If putting the bean in the view scope and using `<f:viewParam>` is not an option, then you'd need to pass the parameter back to the next request by including it as `<f:param>` in the `UICommand` component:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{editUserController.saveUser}"
    style="margin-top:20px;" ajax="false"
    value="#{cms['general.save']}">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{editUserController.id}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: That's a great explanation. With f:param I resolved my problem. Now I better understand the scopes. Thank you so much!