# How to pass a query string parameter?

Tags: jsf-2

We want to pass a variable from a backing bean in request scope of one page as query string parameter to other backing bean in view scope of the next page.

I tried to use `@ManagedParam`, but this signature is not found.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably meant to use `@ManagedProperty`. This isn't useable on a view scoped bean to set a request parameter, because the view scope is of a broader scope than the request scope.

The canonical JSF2 way of passing request parameters and invoking actions on them would be something like the following:

`view.xhtml` view:

```
<h:link value="Edit" outcome="edit">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
</h:link>
```

`edit.xhtml` view:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{edit.id}" />
    <!-- You would normally also convert/validate it here. -->
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{edit.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

`Edit` backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Edit {

    private Long id;

    public void init() {
        // This method will be invoked after the view parameter is set.
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)
- [Communication in JSF2 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: How to do the same from a h:commandLink ,from the action method in the first page's backing bean

Comment: That fires by default a POST request without a query string. You would need to send a redirect as outcome. E.g. `return "/edit.xhtml?id=" + item.getId() + "&amp;faces-redirect=true";` I only don't see how that makes sense while having your initial question in mind. What exactly is the functional requirement?

Comment: Thanks for the reply....I have one requirement ,it can be a h:link so we can f:viewparam , in the second we have to call action method so used the h:commandlink , then we need to redirect to the common page with different values for the query String....

Comment: Ah OK. In the future please ask a new question for that instead of posting it as a comment on an existing but unrelated question.