# JSF lot of GET - Parameters how should i submit them and get them without f:viewparam

Tags: jsf

i have multiple search forms, for five different databases (tables)
each form contains about 30 - 40 search fields, which can be filled.
I need all Params as GET-Params (because of SEO - for pagination)
how can i submit them and get them without define 200  entrys in the .xhtml file
(i think, to get them with facesContext is the way, how to recieve them)

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `<f:viewParam>`, they are available by [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29). If the bean in question is request scoped, you can also use `@ManagedProperty("#{param.name}")` on the property declaration instead. You can only at earliest access them in a `@PostConstruct` method instead of the constructor. You'd also still need setters for them.

Note that you lose JSF-builtin conversion and validation this way. You'd need to do all conversion from `String` to for example `Integer` and do all validation on required parameters yourself instead of letting `<f:viewParam>` do its job.

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, 200 parameters are pretty a lot. Even GET query strings have [its limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request). Does the view contain 50 conditionally rendered/included tables or so? Are you sure that you can't reuse a parameter for multiple purposes and have one common parameter which indicates how the other parameters have to be interpreted?

Comment: Hey BalusC, how can i submit the Form, that i recieve all params as get values inside the url, the JSF PRG doesnt work. (post-redirect-get) with the old style <form action="url" methode="get"> <input name="company"/> .... more... it works, but it should be able to do with jsf or? i see only the param inside the url, if i define it inside metadata with <f:viewparam> ... thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, just use `<form>` instead of `<h:form>`. The `action` is not necessary (will default to current URL) and the `method` is not necessary (will default to GET already). An alternative is `<h:link>` or `<h:button>` should be wherein you nest the parameters as `<f:param>`.

Comment: if i do use h:form with h:link how can i use the values from the h:inputText Component in the f:param attribute of h:link ? thanks

Comment: So you have inputs? Then you can't use `<h:link>`. Use a plain `<input type="submit">` or `<a onclick="submit(); return false;">`.

Comment: last question, do you know, how to build a HtmlCommandLink in a Bean function (with HtmlPanelGrid and binding in view) with a value expression like #{bean.doSomething()} , after that, all problems for the next 3 month should be solved :O

Comment: Can't you just render it conditionally?