# JSF2.0 how do you pass a viewParam to a request scoped backing bean while using a commandButton?

Tags: jsf, facelets, omnifaces

I have the following page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:thehub="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/thehub"
    template="/templates/masterTemplate.xhtml">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam
            id="returnToViewParam"
            name="returnTo"
            value="#{loginMB.returnTo}"
            required="true" />
        <f:viewParam
            id="oauth_verifierViewParam"
            name="oauth_verifier"
            value="#{loginMB.oauth_verifier}" />
        <f:viewParam
            id="oauth_tokenViewParam"
            name="oauth_token"
            value="#{loginMB.oauth_token}" />
        <f:event
            type="preRenderView"
            listener="#{loginMB.preRenderView()}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:define name="body">
        <o:form
            id="loginForm"
            includeViewParams="true">
            <div class="form-vertical well">
                <h4>New Users</h4>
                <h5>
                    <h:link outcome="signup">Click here to create an account</h:link>
                </h5>
                <hr />
                <h4>Existing Users</h4>
                <h:commandButton
                    id="googleLoginCommandLink"
                    styleClass="btn"
                    action="#{loginMB.redirect()}"
                    value="Google">
                    <f:param
                        name="returnTo"
                        value="#{param.returnTo}" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </o:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And the following bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginMB implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String returnTo;

public void redirect() {
    log.debug("redirect() returnTo:{}", returnTo);

......getter/setters
}
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get returnTo bound once the commandButton is clicked. Since this is a login page, I'd really  *not* like to have LoginMB be a @ViewScoped bean.

Advice? Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

EDIT:

- I'm running this on TomEE+ Server v1.5.1 which is served up by MyFaces 2.1.10
- Added full page
- Clarified the problem: Inside the `redirect()` function, returnTo is null

Comment: This should work just fine. Even more, the `<f:param>` is completely unnecessary if you use `<o:form includeViewParams="true">`. You only need it if you aren't using `<o:form>`. To be sure, I have even tried it locally and it works just fine. Your concrete problem is likely caused elsewhere not visible in the information provided so far. What JSF impl/version are you using? Is the `<f:metadata>` properly declared inside the template composition (and thus not outside)?

Comment: Do you have getter and setter methods for `returnTo`?

Comment: yes, there are getter/setters

Comment: @BalusC I added the full page...

Comment: AFAIK, MyFaces doesn't support `<f:metadata>` inside `<ui:composition>`. Try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856847/where-is-the-best-place-for-the-fmetadata-element/9857186#9857186

Comment: @BalusC What's funny is that the o:viewParams work on ViewScoped pages just fine, with the way it is. I did try the ui:define metadata approach however and it did not work

Comment: Things just got more hilarious... I copy/pasted the f:metadata into the masterTemplate and things worked as expected. Sigh...

Comment: oh snap... N/m I got it working with metadata. Not sure what I did wrong, but it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<f:metadata>` is outside `<ui:define>` and is therefore completely ignored. Add an `<ui:insert name="metadata">` to the master template and put the `<f:metadata>` inside an `<ui:define name="metadata">` of the template client.

#### See also:

- [When using <ui:composition> templating, where should I declare the <f:metadata>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856847/where-is-the-best-place-for-the-fmetadata-element/9857186#9857186)

---

Once you fixed that, you can safely remove the `<f:param>` from the command button. This job is already done by `<o:form includeViewParams="true">`. If you didn't have it, then the `<f:param>` would indeed have been mandatory and you'd need to copypaste the same over all command links and buttons in the same form.