# <f:viewParam> not working when using <ui:composition template>

Tags: jsf, templates, facelets, composition, viewparams

I'd like to create a master-detail screen with request params and requestScoped beans but the view param doesn't get filled.

The link that invokes the redirect:

```
<h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="visit" value="#{visitBean.findAllVisits()}">
            <p:column headerText="mdh">
                <p:commandLink action="#{visitDetailBean.seeVisitDetails(visit)}">
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="details.png"/>
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
            ....
```

The method behind it:

```
public String seeVisitDetails(Visit visit) throws IOException {
   return "/pages/mdh-details.xhtml?visitId=" + visit.getId()+ ";faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The details xhtml page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="visitId" value="#{visitDetailBean.currentVisitId}" />
</f:metadata>

<ui:composition template="/templates/masterLayout.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">
    <h:outputText value="#{visitDetailBean.currentVisit.name}"/>
    test
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and last the details Bean:

```
private long currentVisitId;

public void setCurrentVisitId(long currentVisitId) {
    this.currentVisitId = currentVisitId;
}

public long getCurrentVisitId() {
    return currentVisitId;
}

public Visit getCurrentVisit() {
    return visitService.findVisit(currentVisitId);
}
```

currentVisitId is always 0.. I actually can't really find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using templating, anything outside `<ui:composition>` and `<ui:define>` is **ignored**. This includes `<f:metadata>`.

Move it to inside an `<ui:define>` of the `<ui:composition>`.

E.g.

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/masterLayout.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam ... />
    </f:metadata>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
    ...
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [When using <ui:composition> templating, where should I declare the <f:metadata>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856847/when-using-uicomposition-templating-where-should-i-declare-the-fmetadata/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you'd better place `masterLayout.xhtml` in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent direct access.

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/masterLayout.xhtml">
```

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)