# Passing parameters between managed beans with request scope

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

Im working on a web application using `JSF2`. I want to pass parameters from a managed bean in backing bean action and I want to retrive the same parametrs in an other managed bean the both with a request scope.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<f:param>` in the command link/button and use `@ManagedProperty` or `<f:viewParam>` in the target bean or view.

E.g.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{otherBean.submit}">
    <f:param name="foo" value="#{oneBean.foo}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with in `OtherBean`

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.foo}")
private String foo;

// ...
```

Comment: when I test with ViewScope for both bean, I get `The scope of the object referenced by expression #{param.resvDataModel}, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (ReservationActionBean) scope of view`. What I need to do?

Comment: @Cyc: use `<f:viewParam>`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id