# How to navigate with request parameters?

Tags: jsf-2, viewparams

I want to navigate from one page to another page, say from `page1` with `bean1` to `page2` with `bean2`. I need to pass some parameters from `bean1` to `bean2`.

I would like to understand how to use `@ManagedProperty` for parameters and `<f:viewParam>` in `<f:metadata>` portion of `page2`. Say, I have `field1`, `field2` and `field3` available in `bean1` and `bean2` with getters and setters. My understanding is that I will have to define view params in Metadata of `page2`:

Like

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="field1" value="#{bean2.field1}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="field2" value="#{bean2.field2}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="field3" value="#{bean2.field3}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

I am not sure where I use annotations for `@ManagedProperty` to define the parameters `field1`, `field2` and `field3`, in `bean1` or `bean2`.

On `page1` I can use `"page2?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true"`

Can I use the same in one of my methods instead in `page1`, say on response to a submit of commandlink?

If I need to have those three fields in both `page1` and `page2`, can I define those hidden fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify them as `<f:param>` in the `<h:link>` of `page1.xhtml`.

```
<h:link value="Go to page2" outcome="page2">
    <f:param name="field1" value="#{bean1.field1}" />
    <f:param name="field2" value="#{bean1.field2}" />
    <f:param name="field3" value="#{bean1.field3}" />
</h:link>
```

You can then use `<f:viewParam>` (or `@ManagedProperty`, but this allows less fine grained validation) to set them in bean of `page2.xhtml`.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="field1" value="#{bean2.field1}" />
    <f:viewParam name="field2" value="#{bean2.field2}" />
    <f:viewParam name="field3" value="#{bean2.field3}" />
</f:metadata>
```

You do not need to send a POST request by `<h:commandLink>` with `faces-redirect` and `includeViewParam` here. Just a simple GET request by `<h:link>` is much simpler and SEO friendlier.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: Thank you so much BalusC. I really appreciate. I have gone through quite few articales of yours and I just want to say that I love those. You explain so well.

Comment: Sorry just hit the Enter key. I was hoping that you happen to see my post and my wish was granted. Thank you. Here is what I am trying to do. I have a datatable with selectionmode single and on ajax event rowselect, I would like to navigate to another page to show the details (another table) for the selected row. so in my method below for onRowSelect I am navigating to another page.

Comment: 'public String onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) { ConfigurableNavigationHandler configurableNavigationHandler =
               (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)FacesContext.
                 getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

   configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("DetailBean?faces-redirect=true");
   return  "";'        Here I would like to add '&amp;includeViewParams=true'  I am using primefaces          '<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBeanSummary.onRowSelect}" />

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, this is offtopic. Ask a new and clear question :)

Comment: Sure, I can do that but I am still trying to understand or say learn how I can pass parameters when I naviagte to another page using url in a method. I can post another question if you want but please confirm.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have posted another question regarding parameters passing onRowSelect. The matter says "How to navigate to another page on onRowSelect"  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I did not see any link yo mark a question answered so just clicked on the tick mark which turned to green. Please let me know if there is anything else needs to be done. I have visited the link that you posted. Thanks again, BalusC.

Comment: Balusc, Trust all is well on your side. I was trying to psot this simple question, tried ten times at least but ir won't let me put so I thought of adding it here and asking you directly. This is what I was trying to post.

Comment: What is the correct way to set object variable bfield in the follwoing test class?
    public class test {
    
    
    private String afield;
    
    private String bfield;
    
    
    public test() {
    
     buildList();
    
    }
    
    public void buildList() {
    
        some code to derive and populate afield.
    
        this.bfield = this.afield;   //  ( 1)
     
        setBfield(afield);  // (2) say getter and setters do exist 
    
        bfield = afield;  //  (3)
    
    }
What is the right way to do? Is option 1 OK or option 2?

Comment: Did you get a particular error message when you try to post a new question? Try searching http://meta.stackoverflow.com on the exact error message. Contact team@stackoverflow.com if you stucks.

Comment: Sure, will do so. I think it was about the contents, sort of not asking in details my question. I tried to add a line here and there to make that big but was gettiong teh same message.- Peter

Comment: I just added my question. I just need the answer from you. Thanks,

Comment: BalusC, I just posted my question. I know it is a very basic from Java but would like to get it cleared. I hope you won't mind.