# Jsf2.0 forwarding page error without parameter

Tags: jsf-2

Hello i have error when i am forwarding page without parameter. that is happen only in constructor. not happening with methods.

like

```
public EditNewsBean() throws Exception
{
    log.info("In EditNewsBean Constructor");

    Object o1=request.getParameter("countryCode");
    Object o2=request.getParameter("editNewsID");
    if(o1==null || o2==null || o1.toString().length()==0 || o2.toString().length()==0)
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/HeWebEV/admin/ManageNews.jsf");
    }

    setEditNews(Facade.othfac().getTVecNewsFindAllValidTill(request.getParameter("countryCode").toString(),Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("editNewsID"))));
}
```

and when i am passing request form without parameter i am getting error like,

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.efacec.sg.he.plugme.admin.EditNewsBean.
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:185)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:108)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:576)
        at com.efacec.sg.he.plugme.admin.EditNewsBean.<init>(EditNewsBean.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
        ... 63 more
15:07:00,342 INFO  [context] Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.efacec.sg.he.plugme.admin.EditNewsBean.
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:185)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:108)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:576)
        at com.efacec.sg.he.plugme.admin.EditNewsBean.<init>(EditNewsBean.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
        ... 63 more
15:07:00,366 ERROR [[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:576)
        at com.efacec.sg.he.plugme.admin.EditNewsBean.<init>(EditNewsBean.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:185)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:108)
        at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
15:07:00,405 ERROR [[localhost]] Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Exception, location=/error.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot reset buffer after response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.efacec.sg.he.plugme.admin.EditNewsBean.
> ...
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot reset buffer after response has been committed
> ```

The bean is apparently been referenced pretty "late" in the view. A part of the view is already been sent (committed) to the response during render response phase. It's too late then to change the response into a redirect. The server cannot take the already sent bytes back from the client. The server will throw an `IllegalStateException` and the client will end up with a halfbaked response.

You need to perform the redirect *before* any byte is been sent to the client in the response. You can achieve this with a `<f:event type="preRenderView">` listener. Add this somewhere to the view (most self-documenting would be to put this in the top of the template client):

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{editNewsBean.init}" />
```

And move the constructor's code into that method.

```
public void init() {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, don't forget to add an `else {}` block for `setEditNews()`. You don't want that it is called when the condition is eligible for the redirect, right? You would otherwise possibly face a `NullPointerException`. Also, that `toString()` on `getParameter()` is completely unnecessary. Also, you should be gathering request parameters by [`<f:viewParam>` or `@ManagedProperty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id) or at least `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`. You seem to have assigned `HttpServletRequest` as an instance variable of the bean which is a very bad idea. Finally, you're performing a redirect here, not a forward.

Comment: yes. i did just you told me. it is not firing any exception but it is not forwarding page.   public void init() throws Exception
 {
  Object o1=request.getParameter("countryCode");
  Object o2=request.getParameter("editNewsID");
  if(o1==null || o2==null || o1.toString().length()==0 || o2.toString().length()==0)
  {
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/HeWebEV/admin/ManageNews.jsf");
  }
  setEditNews(Facade.othfac().getTVecNewsFindAllValidTill(request.getParameter("countryCode").toString(),Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("editNewsID"))));
 }

Comment: Is the method invoked? If not, then you didn't put it at the right place in the template client.

Comment: yes. that was my mistake. but now i am getting new error.                         19:53:18,234 INFO  [context] Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.efacec.sg.he.plugme.admin.EditNewsBean.init(EditNewsBean.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Comment: Read the "unrelated" part of my answer. You've more serious problems with the code.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for help. Object o1=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("countryCode");
  Object o2=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("editNewsID");if(o1==null || o2==null)
  {
   System.out.println("In Init Method_____MMMMMM");
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/HeWebEV/admin/ManageNews.jsf");
  }
  else
  {
   setEditNews(Facade.othfac().getTVecNewsFindAllValidTill(request.getParameter("countryCode").toString(),Integer.valueOf(re