# getting ManagedBeanCreationException when injecting a managed bean into the other

Tags: jsf-2

In my JSF2-Primefaces3 webapplications I am referencing beans named "HomeBean" from bean "CityBean" I am using ManagedBean annotations and DO NOT have faces-config.xml at all. Please find the code as below:

HomeBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="HmBen")
@SessionScoped
public class HomeBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeBean.class);

    private List<Offer> offersList;

    public HomeBean() {       
    }    
}
```

CityBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="CtyBen")
@SessionScoped
public class CityBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{HmBen}")
    private HomeBean homeBean;         

    public CityBean() {       
    }

    /**
     * Following setters are required as per the documentation for Dependancy
     * Injection of beans to work
     */
    public void setHomeBean(HomeBean homeBean) {
            this.homeBean = homeBean;
    }    
}
```

NOTE: this is just a section of the code due to character limits imposed by Stackoverflow.

I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to set property homeBean for managed bean CtyBen
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:615)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:133)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2377)
```

Does anyone has any clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

Response already committed let me explain what does it mean. on page rendering it is rendering from top to bottom. Server giving response in bytes. after rendering some bytes server gets notification(some if condition on page) that's now you have to render bytes at that time server can not take bytes which already sent to user at that time Server throwing IllegalState exception. Give your .xhtml page. please check following question posted by me a year ago. 
[Jsf2.0 forwarding page error without parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784351/jsf2-0-forwarding-page-error-without-parameter)