# parameter with <f:viewParam> and FacesConverter from CDI

Tags: jsf, glassfish, facelets, el, cdi

It's not clear to me why I'm getting this particular exception, it's a red-herring I think.  The underlying problem could be related to the last line of the exception:  `MessageConverter.getAsObject..0` which should actually be 1501 (the Message ID).  So, why does MessageConverter.getAsObject have the wrong id?

I think that this could be related to the Detail constructor, which is probably passing the wrong parameters to MessageConvert.getAsObject(), in particular the UIComponent object -- probably that reference needs to get instantiated.

relevant EL:

```
        <h:outputLink id="link1" value="detail.xhtml">
            <f:param name="id" value="#{m.getMessageNumber()}" />
             <h:outputText value="#{m.getMessageNumber()}" />
        </h:outputLink>
```

glassfish shows:

```
INFO: MessageConverter.getAsObject..1501
INFO: SingletonNNTP.forward..11
WARNING: 1501
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1501
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:2866)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.SingletonNNTP.getMessage(SingletonNNTP.java:86)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageConverter.getAsObject(MessageConverter.java:21)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.getConvertedValue(UIViewParameter.java:394)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.processValidators(UIViewParameter.java:273)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

INFO: MessageConverter.getAsObject..0
INFO: SingletonNNTP.forward..11
```

MessageConverter, I think that this class is fine so far is it goes:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.mail.Message;

@FacesConverter("messageConverter")
public class MessageConverter implements Converter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MessageConverter.class.getName());
    private static final Level level = Level.INFO;
    private SingletonNNTP nntp = SingletonNNTP.INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        logger.log(level, "MessageConverter.getAsObject..{0}", value);
        Message message = nntp.getMessage(Integer.parseInt(value));
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        Message message = (Message) value;
        return String.valueOf(message.getMessageNumber());
    }
}
```

This is the problem class, Detail, with the constructor, in particular, being suspect:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.mail.Message;

@Named
public class Detail {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Detail.class.getName());
    private static final Level level = Level.INFO;
    private int id = 0;
    private Message message = null;
    private SingletonNNTP nntp = SingletonNNTP.INSTANCE;

    public Detail() {
        MessageConverter mc = new MessageConverter();
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String value = String.valueOf(id);
        UIComponent ui = null;
        Object obj = mc.getAsObject(fc, ui, value);
        message = (Message) obj;
    }

    public int forward() {
        logger.log(level, "Detail.forward..{0}", id);
        id = id + 1;
        logger.log(level, "..Detail.forward {0}", id);
        return id;
    }

    public int back() {
        logger.log(level, "Detail.back..{0}", id);
        id = id - 1;
        logger.log(level, "..Detail.back {0}", id);
        return id;
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getContent() throws Exception {
        return message.getContent().toString();
    }
}
```

reference:

[viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id) which doesn't quite seem to apply as I'm using CDI, @Named, and so cannot use @ManagedProperty, which is the "real" problem.  I suppose I'm not seeing the CDI benefit, as @ManagedProperty looks very nice.

[ProcessingGETRequestParameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters) has a, perhaps, key paragraph:

> Yes, it's a @ManagedBean instead of @FacesConverter! How awkward, but
>   it's not possible to inject an @EJB inside a @FacesConverter in order
>   to do the DB interaction job. The same problem manifests when you use
>   the CDI @Inject to inject a property, you'd need to use @Named instead
>   of @FacesConverter. The Java EE/JSF/CDI guys are working on that for
>   the future JSF 2.2 version, see also JSF spec issue 763. If you really
>   need to have it to be a @FacesConverter (in order to utilize the
>   forClass attribute, for example), then you can always manually grab
>   the EJB from JNDI. See also the next chapter.

which, is, for my purposes, perhaps slightly off-topic as it's EJB related.  However, perhaps that is the exact difficulty which I'm encountering?

Comment: [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058852/inject-to-pass-params-to-a-cdi-named-bean-via-url-gives-jboss-error-on-netbean/10087664#10087664) for the answer to the underlying question.  Please delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The converter is supposed to be used in the `<f:viewParam>`.

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{detail.message}" converter="messageConverter" />
```

This will basically convert the request parameter `id` to object `Message` and then set it in the property behind `#{detail.message}`. You should only supply a setter for it in the `Detail` class, I don't see any one in your bean.

You should not do the conversion job in the constructor of `Detail` class. You should only have a `Message` property, not the `id` or `nntp`. Remove the entire constructor.

```
@Named
public class Detail {

    private Message message; 

    // Getters+setters+actions
}
```

Comment: ok, I understand this answer better.  I still don't understand the converter stuff, however, and am still looking for an explanation which I can understand.  What I did was to omit the bit about the converter and just used the default (generated?) converter.  I dropped that class.