# Implementing @RequestParam in CDI/WELD using Qualifier and InjectionPoint as @HttpParam

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, facelets, cdi

The glassfish error

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/NNTPjsf'
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [NNTPjsf] at [/NNTPjsf]
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
INFO: only once...
INFO: NNTP.loadMessages...
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [FacesContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject net.bounceme.dur.nntp.HttpParamProducer.facesContext]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [FacesContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject net.bounceme.dur.nntp.HttpParamProducer.facesContext]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:243)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:106)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:345)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:330)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

HttpParam:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface HttpParam {
     public String value() default "";
}
```

and

ParamProducer:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class HttpParamProducer {

    @Inject
    FacesContext facesContext;

    @Produces
    @HttpParam
    String getHttpParameter(InjectionPoint ip) {
        String name = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(HttpParam.class).value();
        if ("".equals(name)) {
            name = ip.getMember().getName();
        }
        return facesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(name);
    }
}
```

reference:  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id) and [balusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters), and [glxn](http://www.glxn.net/?p=141)  which has a concrete example I tried to follow.  The glxn post seems exactly what I want, but I can't seem to get it to deploy.

Comment: reference other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058852/inject-to-pass-params-to-a-cdi-named-bean-via-url-gives-jboss-error-on-netbean/10087664#10087664) for underlying problem/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GlassFish is using [WELD](http://seamframework.org/Weld) as the reference implementation for JSR-299: Java Contexts and Dependency Injection for the Java EE platform (CDI).

So, for answering to your question, this is the standard way to have CDI on GlassFish.

Comment: Ok, so I'm then asking the wrong question, but am unsure what to ask here beyond "it doesn't work".  I'm admittedly unsure of what to read without going into EJB.

Comment: Glassfish is the reference implementation.  JBoss isn't

Answer (score 4):

The error is that the CDI engine do not know how to produce a `FacesContext`.

You need to add a snippet that does that - either directly or as a Producer.

Comment: `@Produces @RequestScoped FacesContext getFacesContext() {

      return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

   }`   [weld docs](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/ee.html#d0e4589)   just not quite sure how to implement that into my code.

Comment: Put it in another class next to HttpParamProducer.

Answer (score 4):

Let me repeat what I answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058852/inject-to-pass-params-to-a-cdi-named-bean-via-url-gives-jboss-error-on-netbean/10066003#10066003): Simply do not inject `FacesContext`, use it via `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`. Or just put the producer method you've already found into new class, let's say `FacesContextProducer`.