# Ajax request stop working when using <f:event>

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

I have a JSF form where I have an . On this same page I have an ajax request on a text box. The  is working fine but the ajax does not work. If I remove the , the ajax will work.

Code:

```
   <f:event listener="#{TestComponent.refreshURL}" type="preRenderView" />
   <h:inputText id="name" value="#{TestComponent.test.name}"
                required="true" label="NID" maxlength="14" style="width: 200px">
   <p:ajax update="dob" process="name" listener="#{TestComponent.updateDob()}" />
   </h:inputText>
```

Comment: I found the solution on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570301/prerenderview-disables-ajax