# JSF url parameter dissappears after button click

Tags: jsf, url, parameters, redirect

In addition to: [@Inject to pass params to a CDI @Named bean via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058852/inject-to-pass-params-to-a-cdi-named-bean-via-url/24475659#24475659)
When I click button on page parameter disappears from url. How can I 'freeze' the url to change it only when redirecting?
Using jsf+primefaces.
Regards.

EDIT: Any clues? 
It may be caused by url mapping in web.xml? Because my mapping looks like site_name.xhtml now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sloved by using PreetyFaces. It was only needed to install it, pretty-config.xml I have empty(with only namespaces declaration) and URL is freezed untill redirecting. I dont know it is the standard behaviour...