# Doesn't viewParam work with @RequestScoped bean and ajax events?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, viewparams

After reading some question and answers in stackoverflow (like this [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)) I'm not sure about the possibility of using `viewParam` with `@RequestScoped` bean and ajax events. As you can see in the @BalusC's answer:

> Can be used on a @RequestScoped bean, but it requires the bean to be @ViewScoped if you want > the view parameters to survive any validation failures.

I think it's possible to use `f:viewParam` with `@RequestScoped` bean and at the same time keep the view parameters after validation failures, I mean, you don't need a `@ViewScoped` bean at all.

Probably the necessity of using `@ViewScoped` bean has to do with this spec issue, no?
http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1532

According to that issue the solution will be only available on JSF 2.2.

Comment: Where are all comments and the main answer?