# How to pass parameters between two pages (from p:commandLink with redirect=true and view scoped beans)?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to pass a parameter (a user's id from a datatable) from one page to the next where I am using it (showing the user's details). The problem is that I can not get it. What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? I am using PrimeFaces 5 and JSF 2.2 (also Hibernate 4). Is there any way that I can have the parameter `@PostConstruct` so that I can load the user's details immediately?

The first page with the datable

```
<h:form id="manageUserForm" prependId="false">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="20000"/>
    <p:dataTable id="usersTable" var="user" value="#{manageUsers.users}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{pvtmsg.registeredUsers}
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="ID">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{pvtmsg.username}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{pvtmsg.firstname}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.firstname}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{pvtmsg.lastname}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.lastname}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{pvtmsg.email}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.email}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{pvtmsg.status}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.enabled ? pvtmsg.enabled : pvtmsg.disabled}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
            <p:commandLink action="editUser.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{user.id}" target="#{manageUsers.selectedUser}" />
                <f:param name="userId" value="#{manageUsers.selectedUser}" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Its backing bean

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import models.User;
import utils.PropertyHelper;

@Named(value = "manageUsers")
@ViewScoped
public class ManageUsers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 954672295622776147L;
    private List<User> users = null;
    private String selectedUser = null;

    public ManageUsers() {
        try {
            PropertyHelper helper = new PropertyHelper();
            users = helper.getUsers();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManageUsers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public String getSelectedUser() {
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public void setSelectedUser(String selectedUser) {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }

}
```

The second page

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="userId" value="#{editUserBean.userId}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:form id="editUserForm" prependId="false">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="20000"/>
    <!--nothing yet-->
</h:form>
```

Its backing bean

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "editUserBean")
@ViewScoped
public class EditUserBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 543216875622776147L;
    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found my solution here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsf22-1377252.html and, after some time, the last piece that I needed here here http://www.coderanch.com/t/625319/JSF/java/working-viewParam

Answer (score 2):

Your commandLink doesn't make sense here.  Typically when you want to navigate with a commandLink, you should do a redirect in your backing bean.

If you want to navigate using outcome, then something like this should work for you:

```
<h:link outcome="editUser.xhtml">
  <f:param name="userId" value="#{user.id}" />
</h:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your f:viewParams won't be available during the @PostConstruct method call. You should assign a f:viewAction, since you are using JSF 2.2, to handle business processing on GET parameters.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="userId" value="#{editUserBean.userId}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{editUserBean.processUserId}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

**See also:**

1. [Read this if using JSF older than 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct)
2. [JSF bean: call @PostConstruct function after ViewParam is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261453/jsf-bean-call-postconstruct-function-after-viewparam-is-set)