# How to get request parameter form JSP page in Facelets page?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I have a `login.jsp` page:

```
<form method="post" action="url:8081/login.xhtml">
    Username : <input type="text" name="txtUsername"/>
    Password : <input type="text" name="txtPassword"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

When I submit it, how can I get the `txtUsername` and `txtPassword` parameters in `login.xhtml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All request parameters are in EL available by the `#{param}` map. Thus, this should do:

```
<p>Username: #{param.txtUsername}</p>
<p>Password: #{param.txtPassword}</p>
```

If you need to preprocess them by Java code, better put them as managed properties or view parameters in the backing bean class associated with `login.xhtml`.

Managed property example:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Login {

    @ManagedProperty("#{param.txtUsername}")
    private String username;

    @ManagedProperty("#{param.txtPassword}")
    private String password;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Do here your thing with those parameters.
        System.out.println(username + ", " + password);
    }

    // ...
}
```

View parameter example:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="txtUsername" value="#{login.username}" required="true" />
    <f:viewParam name="txtPassword" value="#{login.password}" required="true" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{login.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Login {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void init() {
        // Do here your thing with those parameters.
        System.out.println(username + ", " + password);
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)