# Passing objects between Views

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

In JSF 2 you can pass around ids, Strings other things that can be sent as request parameters with either `f:viewParam` or `@ManagedProperty` (i.e. discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)).

However, I would like to pass around objects between views, from view1 to view2. My backing beans are `@ViewScoped`. I have tried the following:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{view1Bean.myObject}" target="#{view2Bean.myObject}" />
```

This creates a `view2Bean` on view1, which no longer exists when viewing view2. So, the `view2Bean.myObject` is `null`, because the property was never set on the specific instance of `view2bean`.

I considered using the Flash scope, which seems to be exactly the tool for this. However, I read BalusC somewhere saying that it is broken in Mojarra, which I'm using.

What is the best way to pass around objects between views?

Comment: Normally the session scope is there for objects that need to survive if you change between views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *However, I would like to pass around objects between views, from view1 to view2.*

You could just pass the unique ID of the object as a parameter to the next view and attach a `Converter` to the `<f:viewParam>`.

```html
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.entity}" converter="entityConverter" />
```

---

> *I considered using the Flash scope, which seems to be exactly the tool for this. However, I read BalusC somewhere saying that it is broken in Mojarra, which I'm using.*

This will as of the current Mojarra version only fail whenever the views are in a different path (folder) due to the way how the Flash cookie works. If they are in the **same** path (folder) then it should work just fine.