# JSF ViewScoped variable not surviving redirect to same page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

With the code below, i'm using a listener on the selectOneRadio to redirect to the page with a query string in the url.

The problem is, when i get redirected, the value of `newsTitle` and `selectedNews` are null. Why is this? Is is because i'm doing a redirect using FacesContext?

news.xhtml

```
<h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
<p:inputText id="title" required="true" value="#{contentEditorBacking.newsTitle}" >
    <p:ajax event="blur"/>
</p:inputText>
<h:outputLabel value="Site" style="font-weight: bold;" />
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{contentEditorBacking.selectedNews}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Public" itemValue="Public" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Member" itemValue="Member" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{contentEditorBacking.addNewsArticle}" update="path"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

contentEditorBacking.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ContentEditorBacking {
  private String newsTitle = null;
  private String selectedNews = null;

  public String getNewsTitle() {
    return newsTitle;
  }

  public void setNewsTitle(String newsTitle) {
    this.newsTitle = newsTitle;
  }

  public String getSelectedNews() {
    return selectedNews;
  }

  public void setSelectedNews(String selectedNews) {
    this.selectedNews = selectedNews;
  }

  public void addNewsArticle() throws Exception {

    String year = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)).length() < 2 ? "0"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) : String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String month = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)).length() < 2 ? "0"+(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) : String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
    String day = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).length() < 2 ? "0"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) : String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    String newsPath = null;

    newsPath = "/" + selectedNews + "/News/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/" + newsTitle;

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("news.xhtml?path="+ newsPath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A redirect basically instructs the webbrowser to create a new GET request. This will create a new view and thus also a new instance of the associated view scoped bean. The view scoped bean normally lives as long as you're returning `null` or `void` on (ajax) postbacks (the view scope is namely identified/tracked by the hidden request parameter `javax.faces.ViewState`). That's just how it's specified to work.

Use `<f:viewParam>`/`<f:event type="preRenderView">` to do the initialization job on the new GET request. You can if necessary make the command link a normal GET link so that it's more SEO friendly (search bots don't index POST forms at all).

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: Or is there a way to make a p:ajax call refresh the page or at least update the url in the url bar?

Comment: also, I take it i can't do a `?faces-redirect=true` in the facescontext redirect?

Comment: You can use `update="@all"` to update the entire page, but you cannot change the address bar without telling the browser to send a new request on the given URL (as done by a redirect). The `?faces-redirect=true` does the same under the covers, it's only a convenience when used in action method which can return a string outcome. Just use `<f:viewParam>`, that's where it is for.