# Why is Chrome returning null for sessionID?

Tags: java, servlets, jsf-2, applet

I had a problem a while back where Chrome and Firefox were changing the sessionid when creating a connection from an applet to a backing bean via a servlet in JSF (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149369/session-scoped-managed-bean-not-available-in-servlet-when-using-another-browser/19266794#19266794)). I got around it last time by manually setting the sessionId on the HttpURLConnection connection.

The applet requests a ranking criteria object from the backing bean via the servlet. The user then customises the ranking criteria in the applet (and, in other code, submits the ranking criteria back to the backing bean in order to rank products according to the newly customised ranking criteria).

Now Chrome is setting the request sessionId to null, but Firefox and Internet Explorer work fine.

In the applet:

```
try
    {
        // Get the URL for the servlet.
        URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "editCriteriaServlet");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionID);

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject("Request criteria Object");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Read in the search criteria object.
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        SealedObject sealedObject = (SealedObject)in.readObject();
        in.close();

        // Decrypt the sealed object and get the zipped data.
        SecretKey key = buildSecretKey(crypKeyString);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] baos = (byte[]) sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
        ByteArrayInputStream gis = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos);

        // Unzip and recover the original object.
        GZIPInputStream unzipped = new GZIPInputStream(gis);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(unzipped);
        tempMultipleSlideDataObject = (MultipleSlideDataObject15) ois.readObject();            
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        errorMessage = "Submit criteria file Malformed URL." + ex.toString();
        fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "showErrorMessageDialog_"));
        System.out.println("Model_CriteriaInterface: loadCriteriaObject: MalformedURLException occurred");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errorMessage = "Submit criteria file ERROR exception:" + e.toString();
        fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "showErrorMessageDialog_"));
        System.out.println("Model_CriteriaInterface: loadCriteriaObject: Submit criteria file ERROR exception: " + e.toString());
    }
```

In the servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    System.out.println("Servlet: SessionID: " + ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestedSessionId());

    response.setContentType("application/x-java-serialized-object");

    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        in.close();

        // Get the backing bean and then use that to get the search criteria object.
        ProductSelectionBean productSelection = (ProductSelectionBean)request.getSession().getAttribute("productSelectionBean");

        Object searchObject = productSelection.getSealedRankingCriteria();

        // Send the object, in the response, back to the applet.
        ObjectOutputStream outputToApplet = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        outputToApplet.writeObject(searchObject);
        outputToApplet.flush();          
        outputToApplet.close();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(EditCriteriaServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The following line in the servlet:

```
System.out.println("Servlet: SessionID: " + ((HttpServletRequest)req).getRequestedSessionId());
```

-prints 'null' and the 'productSelection' backing bean is null. Firefox and IE print the sessionId fine.

I suspect that this is a bug in Chrome, however, no one from Chrome has gotten back to me.
Any thoughts? Suggestions to get around it?

Edit update - I found the proper Chrome reporting site (I was Googling Chrome instead of Chromium) [here](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines). Will see if they get back to me through this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if this is what fixed the problem or not, on Chrome, but fixing the:[ViewExpiredException exception problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880031/viewexpiredexception-on-a-wildfly-served-webapp-only-in-a-particular-webbrowser), using BalusC's answer, also appeared to fix this one as well. Either that or Google's guys have fixed it in the last day or so and it is just coincidence.

Because the problem cookies have been cleared, I have been unable to reproduce the error to check if that was actually the cause of the null pointer problem in Chrome. Why it is only affecting Chrome is any ones guess.