# How to validate bean property injected with @ManagedProperty without xml?

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2, annotations, javabeans

I've found a lot of topics discussing how to inject property but none of them suggests validation method.
Here is my bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {       
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.key}")
    private String keyFromUser;
}
```

Currently if param.key is missing among GET params I have

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean myBean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<f:viewParam>` instead. It's like `<h:inputText>`, but then for GET request parameters. It thus allows for registering validators by `validator` attribute or even `<f:validator>` and `<f:validateXxx>` tags. You can even attach a `<h:message>` to it.

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="key" name="key" value="#{myBean.keyFromUser}" validator="myValidator" />
</f:metadata>
<h:message for="key" />
```

You only need to move the `@PostConstruct` job to `<f:event type="preRenderView">`.

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)

Comment: Thank you, but @PostConstruct catches it well. I'd like to use annotations as much as possible.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Always knew about the viewParam tag but I never fully grasped when to use it until now.

Comment: @alehro: I'd like to use the right tool for the job as much as possible. Annotations isn't the holy grail.

Comment: I will upvote this because I think it answers the question better.

Answer (score 1):

I have used JSF-beans pretty little so I must say I don't understand your functional requirement. Perhaps annotate a method @PostConstruct and do validation there? That's were I put stuff that needs to be done after depedency injection is resolved

As a side note that does not answer the question directly I think CDI is very strong for scenarios like this.

Would look something like:

```
@Inject
@RequestParam (validator = MyValidator.class)
```

if you are interested I can supply the actual full implementation

Comment: I'm kind of beginner in JSF too. The funny thing was that I already had  @PostConstruct method. But the exception description is kind of misleading, so, I didn't even look on stacktrace. Thank you.

Comment: If you are beginning and if you like annotations, Consider looking closer at CDI. Glad I could help