# <h:link includeViewParams="true"> does not include URL parameters

Tags: jsf, viewparams

I have a JSF page which is opened by an URL like `test.xhtml?a=15&b=20`.

I have a link which should pass all URL parameters to the next page.

```
<h:link outcome="index" includeViewParams="true" value="Include all url parameters" />
```

I was expecting that when I click on the link it will go to `index.xhtml?a=15&b=20`

But I don't see anything in the URL. Did I understand the `includeViewParams` wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `includeViewParams` will include all `<f:viewParam>` values. You however don't seem to have declared them.

Declare them accordingly in the template client.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="a" />
    <f:viewParam name="b" />
</f:metadata>
```

Note that binding the value to bean property as in `<f:viewParam name="a" value="#{bean.a}" />` is optional. The view parameters in the example are available in the EL scope by `#{a}` and `#{b}`.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)
- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id/4889226#4889226)

Comment: Thanks, it works but doesn't make sense, once you ahve includeViewParams, one would assume that that would automatically copy everything over, instead of specifying again using f:viewParam, the only typing you save is not having to mention value="". Just a thought

Comment: "allow everything" is in first place a bad mentiality in web development world. You don't want to give the client that much freedom. Control what may come in and out.