# How to pass a parameter along with h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, seam, parameter-passing

One of the most common approaches to change locale in JSF+Seam - with `<h:selectOneMenu>`:

```
<h:form  action="#{localeSelector.select}" rendered="false">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{localeSelector.language}" onchange="submit()">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Francais" itemValue="fr" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

I want to implement locale changes with buttons. So, the question is - how to pass the parameter (en, fr, etc.) to update the bean with `<h:commandButton>`? Maybe `<h:inputHidden>` would help?

Comment: Why do you want to send the value? When the form is submitted, the method setLanguage() on your Bean localeSelector will be automatically called.

Comment: Your `<h:form  action="#{localeSelector.select}">` is by the way strange. This is not valid JSF. Did you write this from top of head or something instead of copypasting? @Sante: OP is concretely asking how to do the same with only a bunch of buttons (thus, *without* the dropdown list).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Either pass as method argument (only if your environment supports EL 2.2),

```
<h:commandButton value="English" action="#{localeSelector.change('en')}" />
<h:commandButton value="Deutsch" action="#{localeSelector.change('de')}" />
<h:commandButton value="Français" action="#{localeSelector.change('fr')}" />
```

with

```
public void change(String language) {
    locale = new Locale(language);
    // ...
}
```

---

Or use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`

```
<h:commandButton value="English" action="#{localeSelector.change}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{localeSelector.language}" value="en" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="Deutsch" action="#{localeSelector.change}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{localeSelector.language}" value="de" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="Français" action="#{localeSelector.change}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{localeSelector.language}" value="fr" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
private String language;

public void change() {
    locale = new Locale(language);
    // ...
}
```

---

Or use `<f:param>`

```
<h:commandButton value="English" action="#{localeSelector.change}">
    <f:param name="language" value="en" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="Deutsch" action="#{localeSelector.change}">
    <f:param name="language" value="de" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="Français" action="#{localeSelector.change}">
    <f:param name="language" value="fr" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
public void change() {
    locale = new Locale(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("language"));
    // ...
}
```

*(you can also let JSF automatically set it by a `@ManagedProperty("#{param.language}")`, but this requires the bean to be request scoped, or a `<f:viewParam>`, see also [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id/4889226#4889226))*

---

Enough ways to pass a parameter from view to controller. Take your pick. The `<h:inputHidden>` serves in JSF context a somewhat different purpose and it can only be manipulated by JavaScript in the `onclick` which is ugly.

Comment: Thank you for complete answer! I didn't took advantage of EL 2.2 because there seem to be no method in Seam LocaleSelector class that takes locale as a parameter. I've also tried <f:param>, but it didn't work because the parameter was not bind with localeSelector.language (or maybe I am missing something in these cases?). Anyway <f:setPropertyActionListener> solved my problem

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't expect `#{localeSelector}` to be a Seam-proprietary bean (I don't do Seam). I just assumed outright standard JSF with full control over own code.

Comment: Yes, I got that - I should make it clear in my post. I just wanted to clarify. Thanks again)