# f:param not working in p:fileDownload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using the following code to cause custom validators to skip validation on certain button presses :

```
<p:commandButton ... value="Don't Validate">
    <f:param name="triggerValidation" value="false"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Which is working quite nicely.  However I can't seem to get this to work when using the `<p:fileDownload>` component :

```
<p:commandButton ... value="Don't Validate">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{someWebBean.download()}">
        <f:param name="triggerValidation" value="false"/>
    </p:fileDownload>
</p:commandButton>
```

The `triggerValidation` parameter is `null` by the time it gets to the validator (regardless of whether the `<f:param>` element is a child of the `<p:commandButton>` or `<p:fileDownload>` component).

The code inside the base class of the custom validators get this parameter:

```
Object o = ((HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getParameter("triggerValidation");
```

Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For one thing, `<f:param/>` can be applied only to children of `UIComponent`; `<p:fileDownload/>` is a tag handler. What you're attempting to do now is akin to trying to attach an `<f:param/>` to a `<c:forEach/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the `p:commandButton` contains the `p:fileDownload`, the parameter still has to be on the `p:commandButton`, not the `p:fileDownload`

```
<p:commandButton ... value="Don't Validate">
    <f:param name="triggerValidation" value="false"/>

    <p:fileDownload value="#{someWebBean.download()}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

See also [How to pass a parameter along with h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13049267/5223047).