# Data is not provided correctly after doing a request in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

In the view `main_app.xhtml` there are 5 different fields, each of them contains a button, when clicking in this button it has to open the view `chart_xxx.xhtml`, and it will show a chart with the different data related to the field
i.e.:

General Rating will show some data in the Chart
Clean Rating will show some different data in the Chart
etc

When I click the button the `buildGraph()` method is called several times, usually 2 or 3, and it some of those requests the parameter sent in the request is shown and in other is not, I don't know why this is happening, therefore
I decided to store that parameter sent by the request in the session but... I don't know why, if I go back to `main_app.xhtml`, click in a different button, the view `chart_xxx.xhtml` will show the data from the previous request sent,
but if I go back again to `main_app.xhtml` and click again in the same button, the correct data is shown.
For example:

1. I click on General Rating button, its data is shown on the chart.
2. Go back to `main_app.xhtml`
3. Click on Clean rating
4. Data from General Rating is shown.
5. Go back to `main_app.xhtml`
6. Click on Clean rating again
7. Data from Clean rating is shown correctly

I have read this topic [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times) several times but I couldn't find a way to adapt it to my feature.
Furthermore, if I use `@RequestScoped`, the chart is shown empty the second time I click on a button to show it.

Please, omit syntactic issues, I had to change some names due to my company policies so it cannot be identified and also translate from my language so there might be some syntactic issue but only from the translation.
I also omitted Service and DAO classes because they are working fine, they return what I expect from them.

I work with Java 1.6, JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 6.0

So, I need help solving this issue or if someone knows a better approach, I am all eyes but in this case, please, try to make an extended answer because I really cannot think about any other way.

**EDIT 1**

I've removed Setter and Getter in order to make my code more clear for you, also removed some code assigning attributes to the Chart, but all these things are in my original code and working fine.

**PollGraphicBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="pollGraphic")
@SessionScoped
public class GraficosEncuestaBean {

private LineChartModel graphicLine;

public GraficosEncuestaBean(){
    if(graphicLine == null){
        this.buildGraph();
    }
}


public void buildGraph(){
    HttpServletRequest parameterMap = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);

    String general = "";
    String clean = "";

    String date1 = "01-03-2017 00:00";
    String date2 = "30-04-2017 00:00";

    if(parameterMap != null){

        if(general != null){
            general = parameterMap.getParameter("general");
            session.setAttribute("hidden", general);
        }else if(clean != null){
            clean = parameterMap.getParameter("clean");
            session.setAttribute("hidden", clean);
        }

        this.buildGraphicFinal(date1,date2, (String) session.getAttribute("hidden"));


    }
}

private void buildGraphicFinal(String date1, String date2, String value){

    this.graphicLine = new PollGraphicService().getGraphicData(date1, date2, value);

}


}
```

**chart_xxx.xhtml**

```
 <ui:define>
    <p:panel>
        <h:form>
            <p:chart type="line" model="#{pollGraphic.graphicLine}" />
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>   
 </ui:define>
```

**main_app.xhtml**

```
 <ui:define>


    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:column>
            <p:panel>
                <div>
                    <h:form prependId="false">
                        <input type="hidden" value="General Rating" 
 name="general" id="general"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Get results" 
 actionListener="#{pollGraphic.buildGraph}" onstart="location.href = 
 '/XXX/chart/chart_xxx.xhtml'"/>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </p:panel>
        </p:column>  
        <p:column>


                    <h:form prependId="false">
                        <input type="hidden" value="Clean Rating" 
  name="clean"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Get results" 
  actionListener="#{pollGraphic.buildGraph}" onstart="location.href = 
  '/XXX/chart/chart_xxx.xhtml'"/>

                        </h:form>
                </div>
            </p:panel>
        </p:column>

    </p:panelGrid>
   </ui:define>
```

Comment: Why are you using the parameterMap this way and populating the session that way... Very oldschool... And trry reducing the code in your question. Way to much noise... [mcve] please

Comment: I added all the necessary code that is involved in my problem, and I know it is not the best way to do it, but like I said, it is the only approach I was able to find due to the buildGraphic method being called several times, I am wide open to suggestions about how to manage it in a better way.

Comment: No, much of the code is not related to the problem. All the divs, br style etc panelgrid etc irrelevant. Oh and prependId="false" should not be used.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render. And you should not do any work in a constructor... Not even lazy... Use the @PostConstruct annotation...

Comment: I reformated my xhtml code erasing many of it, I cannot try now @PostConstruct and delete prependId, will do it tomorrow when I get to my office.

Comment: Yes but only if you clear things up (you can clear up even more) we can see what the real usecase is and maybe where you go wrong...

Comment: Ok, I cleared up and I don't know if there is something else to be cleared up, if so, please, tell me.

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried with `@PostConstruct` and it solved my issue with the method being called several times but now it doesn't get the parameter I am sending; I want a parameter send to the Bean so it will get different data according to the parameter.

Comment: Then use parameters the normal way. Pass it as a param in the method call

Comment: And there are q/a about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048930/how-to-pass-a-parameter-along-with-hcommandbutton

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `@SessionScoped` to `@ViewScoped` or even `@RequestScoped`

Comment: I said in my comment I tried with `@RequestScoped` and it just doesn't show the chart and with `@ViewScoped` it throws a `NotSerializableException`

Comment: Sorry I missed that comment. How are you navigating back in Step 2, 5?

Comment: I have a menu in the top bar, 2 menuItems with an action in them, on of them links to `main_app.xhtml` with faces-redirect=true, so that's what I use.

Comment: BTW, your bean should implement `serializable`.

Comment: @SirajK: There are many other things 'wrong'... Looks like the code above contains many http://www.xyproblem.info related 'fixes'...

Comment: @Kukeltje I now my approach is bad but like I said already, it’s the only thing that came to my mind so please, if you are willing to help and have a better idea, it is welcome but only saying that everything is wrong won’t help me at all, I explained what I want to do and pasted my approach and explained my issue too.

Comment: @SirajK, I will do that.

Comment: Why the downvote? I am certain that changing scope will fix the issue