# Conversion Error setting value "UserID" for 'null Converter'

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, metadata, javabeans, converters

I getting a Conversion Error when try delete or edit a user from a table in my application. The value is being passed in the metadata from the `listUser.xhmtl` to the `deleteUser.xhtml` page. The value is being passed in the metadata but for some reason upon calling the delete action I get the `Conversion Error setting value "someemail@somedomain.com" for 'null Converter'`. The user id is a String.

This is the url after requesting the userDelete.xhmtl:

```
http://localhost:8080/lavpWebApp/user/deleteUser.xhtml?user=someemail%40somedomain.com
```

This is the userList.xhmtl simplified:

```
<h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
                            <h:link outcome="/user/editUser.xhtml" value="Edit User">
                                <f:param name="user" value="#{item.email}"/>
                            </h:link>                            
                        </h:column>

                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                            <h:link outcome="/user/deleteUser.xhtml" value="Delete User">
                                <f:param name="user" value="#{item.email}"/>
                            </h:link>
                        </h:column>
```

This is userDelete.xhtml simplified:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="user" value="#{userController.user}" converter="#{userConverter}"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:body>
        Do you want to delete #{userController.user.name}?
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton action="#{userController.deleteUser()}"
                             value="Delete"/>
            <h:commandButton action="#{userController.doCancelDeleteUser()}"
                             value ="Cancel"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

This is the Converter class:

```
@ManagedBean
@FacesConverter(value="userConverter")
public class UserConverter implements Converter{

    @EJB
    private UserSellerEJB userEjb;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }
        if(!value.matches("\\d+"))
        {
            throw new ConverterException("The value is not a valid email: " + value);
        }

        String id = value.toString();
        return userEjb.findUserById(id);

    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if(value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if(!(value instanceof UserSeller))
        {
            throw new ConverterException("The value is not a User: " + value);            
        }

        String id = ((UserSeller) value).getEmail();
        return (id != null) ? id.toString() : null;
    }

}
```

This is the userController class simplified:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UserController{

    @EJB
    private UserSellerEJB userEJB;

    private UserSeller user = new UserSeller(); 
    private List<UserSeller> usersList = new ArrayList<UserSeller>();

    // ------------------------------------------------------------- Constructor
    public UserController() {
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------- Business Methods

    public String doCreateUser()
    {
        user = userEJB.createSeller(user);
        usersList = userEJB.findAllSellers();
        return "listUser?faces-redirect=true";        
    }

        // update user

        public void PreRenderView()
        {
            if(user == null)
            {
                user = new UserSeller();
            }            
        }

        public String doUpdateUser()
        {
            if(user.getEmail() != null)
            {
                userEJB.updateSeller(user);
            }
            else
            {
                userEJB.createSeller(user);
            }

            return "listUser?faces-redirect=true";
        }

    public String deleteUser()
    {
        userEJB.deleteSeller(user);
        return "listUser?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String doCancelDeleteUser()
    {
        return "listUser?faces-redirect=true";
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        usersList = userEJB.findAllSellers();       
    }
```

Comment: try assigning a `name` to the `@ManagedBean` annotation and using that instead to access the converter. Make sure it's different from the one you're already using in the `@FacesConverter`

Comment: A `@ManagedBean` can't have the `@FacesConverter` annotation. Remove the `@ManagedBean` annotation ant the code will work. By the way, you're mixing JSF with CDI, it will be better to study both and their differences. Related: [Inject a EJB into a JSF converter with JEE6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2019495/1065197).

Comment: @kolossus thanks. I have added the `name` to the `@ManagedBean`, I used `@ManagedBean(name="userSellerConverter")` but still it's giving the same error.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, that's not accurate. A converter can also be annotated with `@ManagedBean`. I know because I've done it several times. It's the only way the converter can have access to `@Inject` type resources

Comment: @kolossus check the link in my comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, saw the winning answer. Also saw http://stackoverflow.com/a/8919591/1530938. I'm not saying it's pretty or correct, but it can be done

Comment: @kolossus and @LuiggiMendoza I have tried both methods both are not working. I have used @Kolossus approach before and it worked, but this time it is not working. I have tried different methods, I have even tried "@Inject" and using `@FacesConverter("ForClass= UserController.class")` I really don't know where the problem is. Is there any other suggestions, you guys may have.

Comment: @kolossus after using your suggestion and restarting the server. I got this error instead `{0}: Conversion error occurred.` Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lv10, from everything you've put here, this may just be your app server/ide screwing with you(eclipse can be a b****). I'd suggest you move on with an alternative path to setting up that object like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13332562/1530938) so you don't spend too much time on this one method

Comment: Technically, Luiggi is right that a `@ManagedBean` cannot have a `@FacesConverter` annotation. It's usually the one or the other, not both.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thank you very much. I now better understand how custom converters work. @BalusC answer solved the problem, I just removed faces annotation and changed to `@Named`. It works now beautifully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `null converter` in the exception message indicates that the converter instance cannot be found. Since you're referencing the converter as a managed bean by `converter="#{userConverter}`, it would only be found if it's annotated with `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` and if the class is located in the WAR (and thus not in the EJB/EAR or elsewhere!).

The `@FacesConverter` annotation isn't been used in this construct and in fact superfluous — and only confusing to starters. Remove that annotation. The `@EJB` works indeed only in managed beans.

If really in vain (I could however not explain why), try managing it by CDI instead: replace the JSF `@ManagedBean` annotation by the CDI `@Named` annotation. You're apparently already successfully managing front controller beans by CDI.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the converter seems to be designed to convert based on a technical ID (a DB primary key), not an email address. An email address can never match `\d+` (which is regex for "digits only"). Make sure that you're not confusing email address with ID.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed suggestions. I have followed your instructions, I removed the `@FacesConverter` annotation, I have also replaced the `@ManagedBean` annotation for `@Named("userConverter")`. I have also removed the regex condition. I'm using the email as an id for this `User` that is why I used email. Problem is now fixed. Thank you very much.

Comment: BalusC - onie question: I am new to JSF and have read that @FacesConverter is required and would like to fully understand why I needed to remove it in this case. Could you extend a little bit your explanation on why we removed it for this converter? - Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because you want to inject an `@EJB` in it. The `@FacesConverter` (and `@FacesValidator`) is however not a supported injection target. This oversight is fixed in upcoming JSF 2.2.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it now.