# How to get parameters from the URL in JSF properly?

Tags: jsf

I believe there are 2 ways to get the parameters from the URL in JSF.

One being in the bean:

```
Map<String, String> params =FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                   getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String parameterOne = params.get("parameterOne");
```

and the other one being in the facelets page

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="parameterOne" value="#{bean.parameterOne}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Obviously the latter one will require a field in the class and getter / setter for it.

Besides that, what are the differences between these 2 different approaches? Which one should be preferred?

Comment: Pretty neat article on a disadvantage of `<f:viewParam>` http://jdevelopment.nl/stateless-stateful-jsf-view-parameters/

Comment: @Andy: which is solved by OmniFaces `<o:viewParam>` (from the very same author as the article you linked there).

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I actually found this in one of your [blog entries](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/stateless-view-parameter.html). I thought OP might like. Heck, I learned about this myself just a few hours ago.

Comment: Set param in view associating with bean attribute, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495797/how-to-get-request-parameters-from-view-scoped-jsf-bean

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think this may help:
[Get Request and Session Parameters and Attributes from JSF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550448/get-request-and-session-parameters-and-attributes-from-jsf-pages)

In fact, there should be a query:

```
<h:outputText value="#{param['id']}" />
```

Comment: I think the question is "How do I get a URL-parameter in my View, without adding a method in the view?"

Comment: Additionally, you can use `<h:outputText value="#{param.id}" />` for a more friendly syntax.