# Setting a bean property from a request parameter

Tags: jsf, parameters, request

What is the correct (best) way to set a managed bean's property from a request's parameter?

The URL for my JSF page looks something like this:

```
https://eample.com/app/faces/page.xhtml?ts=2012-01-05T10:00:00.000
```

I have found that I can read the parameter using the following:

```
<h:outputText value="#{param['ts']}" />
```

But what I really need to do is set my bean's property from this value.  So what
is the best JSF way code this so I get something which results Java code like this:

```
myBean.setTimestamp(request.getParameter("timestamp"));
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a JSF managed bean with request scope, inject it as a managed property:

```
import javax.faces.bean.*;

@ManagedBean @RequestScoped
public class ReqBean {
    @ManagedProperty("#{param.ts}") private String ts;

    public String getTs() {
        return ts;
    }

    public void setTs(String ts) {
        this.ts = ts;
    }
}
```

If the bean is in a broader scope, you will need to look it up programmatically:

```
private String lookUpTs() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                       .getExternalContext()
                       .getRequestParameterMap()
                       .get("ts");
}
```

If you are using CDI beans, you will need to consider other options (see [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/jsf-cdi-and-el.html) for one approach.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question history, you're using JSF2, so just the [`<f:viewParam>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) should do.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="ts" value="#{myBean.timestamp}" />
</f:metadata>
```

That's it.

As `<f:viewParam>` extends from `UIInput` (like `<h:inputText>` and so on), you can even perform conversion and validation on it using e.g. `<f:convertDateTime>` and `required="true"`.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="ts" name="ts" value="#{myBean.timestamp}" required="true">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS" />
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
...
<h:message for="ts" />
```

This way the `#{myBean.timestamp}` can be a fullworthy `java.util.Date` property. Any conversion and validation errors will end up in the `<h:message>` associated with `<f:viewParam id>`.

Note that unlike with `@ManagedProperty`, the `#{myBean}` can just be a `@ViewScoped` one.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)