# primefaces datatable not binding

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

i have a problem with my primefaces datatable, rows are empty.

```
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="../shared/commonLayout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{UserManagedBean.userList}" style="width: 40%">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="FirstName" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.firstname}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

```java
@ManagedBean(name = "UserManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean {
//..
/**
     * Get Users List.
     * 
     * @return List - User List
     */
    public final List<User> getUserList() {
        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        userList.addAll(getUserService().getItems());
        return userList;
    }
}
```

i'm using spring, hibernate, jsf managed beans.
can somebody help me please?
[image]

Comment: Is your userList populated properly from the bean?

Comment: yes,i have 2 elements in the database and my user list is charged successfully

Comment: Post the code of `UserManagedBean`, without it we can only guess. Are there any errors in the console? Is the bean's name with capital `U`, or maybe `userManagedBean`?

Comment: @ManagedBean(name = "UserManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean {/**
  * Get Users List.
  * 
  * return List - User List
  */
 public final List<User> getUserList() {
  userList = new ArrayList<User>();
  userList.addAll(getUserService().getItems());
  return userList;
 }

Comment: Its a long shot but try to use columns like this              <p:column headerText="LastName">
 <h:outputText value="#{user.lastname}" />
</p:column>

Comment: And the rest of the code? Anything involving `userList`?

Comment: @ManagedBean(name = "UserManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean {/**
  * Get Users List.
  * 
  * return List - User List
  */
 public final List<User> getUserList() {
  userList = new ArrayList<User>();
  userList.addAll(getUserService().getItems());
  return userList;
 }

Comment: <p:dataTable id="fentitytypes" var="fentitytype" value="#{FentityTypeManagedBean.fentitytypeList}" style="width: 40%">
             <p:column headerText="SYSID">
                <h:outputText value="#{fentitytype.sysid}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Ref">
                <h:outputText value="#{fentitytype.ref}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Title">
                <h:outputText value="#{fentitytype.title}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable> same problem with p:column headertext="...

Comment: You could put that code in the question, not the comment, it's almost useless here.

Comment: Just saying as a side note : What is need to use the `addAll()` method of the said `java.util.List`? You can just assign a return value arriving from the service layer (EJBs or whatever). Are you extremely sure about the return value of this service method - `getUserService().getItems()`? Does the `getItems()` method return some concrete rows hereby not a `null` or empty list?

Comment: ![][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hnZpG.png

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted should work if:

- `getUserList()` returns some rows, filled with some data
- `User` class has a field `firstname` with getter and setter (note the case, `n` is lowercase in your column)
- That `firstname` field is populated (not empty)

Can you verify the above?

Comment: What if you remove `final` from the getter?

Comment: nothing happened, i think it's not a problem of 'final' cause add user is working fine

Comment: Is the getter called at all? Is the screenshot from getter or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to correct in your code:

1. Don't do business logic in the getter; move that code into a `@PostConstruct`
2. Don't back a page with a `@SessionScoped` bean; it's a design-smell and almost never ends well. Use the `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped` instead.
3. Everything outside a `<ui:composition/>` is ignored by the facelets engine. What that means is that all the tags you've defined outside it will have no effect (the `<h:body/>`) for example

Related Reading:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)
- [Request parameter is null during postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567920/request-parameter-is-null-during-postback/14570012#14570012)