# p:menuitems with f:param for pass parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, parameters

I have menu bar `<p:submenu>` which have phone brands as its menu items these menu items should redirect to same page but loading data should different. So I tried to use param and viewparam to catch the brand name

Menu bar JSF code

```
<p:submenu label="PHONES">
    <p:menuitem value="Apple" outcome="phones" >                               
        <f:param name="brand" value="Apple" />
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Motorola" outcome="phones" >
        <f:param name="brand" value="Motorola"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Nokia" outcome="phones">
        <f:param name="brand" value="Nokia"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Samsung" outcome="phones">
        <f:param name="brand" value="Samsung"/>
    </p:menuitem>
</p:submenu>
```

paramview code - this code is in different xhtml file. coded beginning of body

```html
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>  
        <f:viewParam name="brand" value="#{phonesBean.brand}" />  
    </f:metadata>
```

PhonesBean

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PhonesBean implements Serializable {

    private String brand;
    private List<PhoneSummary>phoneList = new ArrayList<PhoneSummary>();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of PhonesBean
     */
    public PhonesBean() {
        getPhoneModelList();
    }

    private void getPhoneModelList(){
        brand=MenuItemManage.phoneBrand;
        DbPhones dbPhones = new DbPhones();
        phoneList=dbPhones.getPhonesSummary(brand);    
    }
}
```

Now when `<p:menuitem>` is clicked it redirects to page with parameter tagging like "brand=Nokia" but I can't catch it from `<f:viewParam>` and set it to a bean variable. How to fix this?

Comment: `<f:viewparam>` goes in `<f:metadata>` section as shown here: [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = “#{param.id}”)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4888942/1065197)

Comment: could you please show me the error here?

Comment: Refer to [Communication in JSF 2: Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters). Note that links in comments are meant for you to check the info provided there (this includes the links inside that Q/A as well).