# How to post form values from one JSF page to another

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, view-scope

I've two web pages first.xhtml and second.xhtml, the first.xhtml has a form and is backed by a view scoped bean since it involves ajax postbacks to same view. Now on submit of this form depending on the submit method outcome which is in view scoped bean of first.xhtml, page navigates to second.xhtml which has to show the first.xhtml's form values. How can I implement this ? I understand the viewscoped bean exists until the view exist.

Thanks to [this page](http://balusc.blogspot.ch/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Comment: You could add data to `#{flash}` object so that it would survive a redirect.

Comment: Is forward possible with flash ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)