# Order initializing managed bean

Tags: jsf, initialization, managed-bean

```
<h:form>
<p:panel>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <ui:include src="../Filtros/FiltroGenerico.xhtml" />
        <p:column >
            <p:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{pantallaBB.buscar}" />
        </p:column>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

In `@Postconstruct` of `#{pantallaBB}` I active and desactive some filter in my BB `FiltroGenerico` but I can read this because first load `@Postconstruct` of `#{filtroGenerico}` and after load `@Postconstruct` of `#{pantallaBB}`. I resolve add this line `<h:outputText value="#{pantallaBB.anyAtribute}" style="display : none;" />` before `<ui:include>` but I don´t liked. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{PantallaBB.doSomeThing}" />
</f:metadata>
```

See also: [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)

Answer (score -1):

You can use 
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{PantallaBB}")
PantallaBB pantallaBB;

to call the class in FiltroGenerico.java and in FiltroGenerico @Postconstruct method call pantallaBB's @Postconstruct like pantallaBB.init() if @Postconstruct method named init.

Comment: The problem with this solution are that **FiltroGenericoBB** calls many BB.