# At what point is a field using @ManagedProperty annotation set?

Tags: jsf, managed-property

At what point is a field using `@ManagedProperty` annotation set?
Specifically, does it happen during construction or after construction?

Comment: It happens immediately after bean construction. It is explained over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4889226/1391249).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any field using @ManagedProperty annotation is set immediately after the constructor runs. So the same field can be used in a @PostConstruct method. That is what my main concern was while asking this question. For more lucid details please refer to the following excellent post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889226/1391249