# Display particular data record using JSF <h:commandLink>

Tags: jsf, controller, ejb, javabeans

I have a list of books which are stored in database. when i click any one record to see the details of that book, it displays all the book details stored in database. Following figures shows more details scenario:

[image: List of books stored in database]

[image: Details of all books stored in database]

As shown in above figures; when i click the `Book Title` or `Book Title 2`, it is display both book details. However, i want only that particular clicked details.

Following is my code where `book title` is displayed with `command link`:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Title"/>
     </f:facet>
   <h:form>
     <h:commandLink action="#{itemController.doBookDetails}"> <h:outputText value="#{bit.title}"/></h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:column>
```

Following is the code of method `doBookDetails`

```
public String doBookDetails() {

        return "bookDetails.xhtml";
    }
```

I know problem is in above method because in `bookDetails.xhtml` there is list which contains the all books record. I have to run query but i dont know how to pass any variable with clicked linked which indicate me which record has been clicked ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is in your `bookDetails.xhtml` page and in the managed bean. Looks like in it you're retrieving the data for all your books, which is wrong. You must send the id of the book to retrieve its details and show them in your page.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is how to pass id by clicking the link ?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2456295/1065197