# how to pass paramter with url in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456295/how-to-pass-url-parameters-to-jsf) to solve my issue but it's not showing the parameter value in url just like http://www.example.com/jsfApp.jsf?param1=value1&param2=value'

my issue is when i post the value just like

```
<h:outputLink value="jsfApp.jsf">
    <f:param name="param1" value="value1" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</h:outputLink>
```

then it will be show in url just like this

```
http://www.example.com/jsfApp.jsf?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Comment: post your code so that we can find what you have missed

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: it's only show in url http://www.example.com/jsfApp.jsf

Comment: Are you in JSF 1.x or 2.x? If 2.x use `h:link` and an `outcome` attribute

Comment: i'm using 2.x. can you provide some demo code how to use h:link and outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being your outcome `jsfApp`, you only need to specify it like that:

```xml
<h:link value="Go with params" outcome="jsfApp">
    <f:param name="param1" value="value1" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</h:link>
```

Have a look at [1.2 point](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/).

Comment: when i click in link which method will call in bean class.

Comment: it's working good. but i'm unable to get this value in bean class

Comment: It is not a method in your bean class. It is an `outcome`, it only specifies where you want to go and which parameters to include. Google 'JSF implicit navigation' for more details.